# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre require, require_once, include, include_once en PHP?

Tags: php

En PHP hay varias formas de agregar archivos en otros usando:

- `require()`
- `require_once()`
- `include()`
- `include_once()`

Pero ¿hay alguna diferencia entre ellos?

¿Hay casos específicos en los que es mejor usar uno u otro?

El objetivo de la pregunta es tener una idea clara sobre si en algunos casos conviene usar uno u otro, para tener un código más optimizado teniendo en cuenta el consumo de recursos u otros criterios, por eso,  conviene que en la respuesta sea indicado si el uso de uno u otro afecta en mayor o menor grado la cantidad de memoria que se consume u otros detalles importantes.

Comment: Creo que con las respuesta de @cnbandicoot puedes imaginar los distintos casos donde conviene usar cada una. Por lo general yo uso `require`, porque se que voy a necesitar lo que está en ese archivo... si usara `include` y no llegara a estar el archivo, es muy probable que me salte un error porque no esta la función, clase, etc. Por otro lado `require_once` lo usaría, por ejemplo, en alguna función/acción recursiva

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Include**

> inserta en nuestro programa un código procedente de otro archivo, en caso de que dicho archivo no exista o tenga errores en su interior nuestro programa mostrará un **warning** pero **seguirá funcionando**.

**Require**

> Funciona de manera similar a include, pero en este caso, si el archivo no existe o contiene errores, nuestro programa no
>   funcionará y obtendremos un **fatal error** en el log

**Include_once y Require_once**

> Funcionan exactamente de la misma forma que las anteriores salvo que
>   impiden la carga de un mismo fichero varias veces.

**Conclusión final:**

Podemos pensar en utilizar **include** cuando el archivo a introducir no sea determinante respecto al funcionamiento de nuestro programa. **Require** cuando dicho archivo sea necesario para el correcto funcionamiento de nuestro programa.

Finalmente se debe utilizar las variantes con **_once** cuando nuestro programa tenga unas dimensiones considerables y pueda darse el caso de que la inclusión del fichero se produzca varias veces. Estas últimas variantes hay que usarlas solo en casos excepcionales ya que consumen más recursos que las anteriores.

Answer (score 15):

Según la documentación oficial de **[PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/)**:

> [`require`](http://php.net/require) es idéntico a `include` excepto que en caso de fallo
>   producirá un error fatal de nivel **`E_COMPILE_ERROR`**. En otras
>   palabras, éste detiene el script mientras que include sólo emitirá una
>   advertencia (**`E_WARNING`**) lo cual permite continuar el script.

---

> La sentencia [`require_once`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.require-once.php) es idéntica a `require` excepto que
>   PHP verificará si el archivo ya ha sido incluido y si es así, no se
>   incluye (`require`) de nuevo.

---

> La sentencia [`include_once`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include-once.php) incluye y evalúa el fichero
>   especificado durante la ejecución del script. Tiene un comportamiento
>   similar al de la sentencia `include`, siendo la única diferencia de
>   que si el código del fichero ya ha sido incluido, no se volverá a
>   incluir, e `include_once` devolverá **`TRUE`**. Como su nombre indica,
>   el fichero será incluido solamente una vez.