# ¿Como manejar rutas de archivos PHP?

Tags: php, mvc

Hola chicos por mucho tiempo he querido introducirme en el mundo PHP pero nunca me habia terminado de dar el gusto, una de las cuestiones que tengo es como manejar las rutas de los include y require ya si tienes varias carpetas el incluir los archivos php de otras carpetas es complejo.

Ejemplo si tengo una configuracon de mi sistema similar a esto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es moverme entre las rutas ya que si quiero incluir el archivo config.php en la clase WorkerImp.php no se como hacerlo por el tema de las rutas, PHP me dice que el archivo no puede ser incluido.

He leido sobre el crear un archivo de configuracion con las rutas base pero llego a la misma conclusion para poder acceder a esas rutas constantes necesito agregar config.php

Comment: Si entiendo bien tu pregunta seria.. ¿Comopuedo incluir un archivo a mi controlador de php? o mejor planteada... ¿Como se manejan las rutas de archivos en php?

¿Estoy en lo correcto?

Comment: @AlejoFlorez la segund creo seria lo mas correcto

Comment: Yo no veo ninguna clase llamada `WorkImp.php`  y además... ¿incluir un archivo de configuración en una clase? El único caso en que uso un archivo de configuración en una clase es para conectar a la base de datos, sin pasar por `include`, sino usando `parse_ini_file`. Generalmente uno no quiere dar acceso a los archivos de configuración así tan fácilmente.

Comment: @A.Cedano disculpa la clase  no es WorkImp es WorkerImp ya lo he corregido.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

En general los `include`, como los `require` funcionan así:

#### Si los archivos están en el mismo directorio del script

```
include ("archivo.php");
```

#### Si los archivos están en otro directorio

Si el archivo está en el directorio padre del script, se pone `../` delante del nombre del archivo:

```
include ("../archivo.php");
```

**`../`** sirve para retroceder entre directorios.

Se puede usar también `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` como punto de referencia.

Si `config.php` está en el directorio raíz. Se podría hacer un `include` de éste archivo desde `WorkerImp.php` mediante:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/config.php");
```

O mediante:

```
include("../../config.php");
```

aquí `../../` retrocede dos directorios desde donde se encuentra el script. Es decir, retrocede `imp>dao>` buscando `config.php` en el directorio que encuentra en la raíz de la App.

---

### Otra posibilidad

Yo he implementado lo siguiente, para permanecer **independiente** de cualquier posible cambio de ruta.

He creado un archivo llamado `dirs.php` en el que tengo definidas todas las rutas de mi proyecto. Coloco ese archivo en el root (directorio raíz).

```
<?php 
define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
define('CONTROLLER_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'controller/');
define('MODEL_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'model/');
define('DAO_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'dao/');
define('IMP_PATH', DAO_PATH.'imp/');
...
etc

?>
```

Luego, cuando necesito incluir algún archivo del proyecto:

```
include_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dirs.php');
include (DAO_PATH."PersonaDao.php");
```

Nótese que uso `include_once`, para que no vuelva a incluirlo si otro archivo del proyecto lo ha hecho (para entender la diferencia entre `include` e `include_once` puedes consultar: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre require, require_once, include, include_once en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66754/29967)

**¿Qué ventaja tiene usar este método?**

Si por algún motivo tengo que cambiar una ruta del directorio `Dao`, no tengo que revisar todas las partes donde intervienen los include de ese directorio, sólo cambio el valor de `DAO_PATH` y listo.

**¿Qué desventaja?**

Al incluir el archivo `dirs.php` estarás incluyendo algunas constantes que quizá no vayas a utilizar. Tampoco son cientos o miles de constantes, por lo cual no afectará al rendimiento de tu programa.

---

### La mejor de las posibilidades

Sería usar **Autocarga de clases (Autoloader)**, dejo aquí sólo parte de la [introducción en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.autoload.php), para abrir el apetito:

> Muchos desarrolladores que escriben aplicaciones orientadas a objetos
> crean un fichero fuente de PHP para cada definición de clase. Una de
> las mayores molestias es tener que hacer una larga lista de
> inclusiones al comienzo de cada script (uno por cada clase).
>
> En PHP 5 esto ya no es necesario. La función
> [`spl_autoload_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.spl-autoload-register.php) registra cualquier número de
> autocargadores, posibilitando que las clases e interfaces sean
> cargadas automáticamente si no están definidas actualmente. Al
> registrar autocargadores, a PHP se le da una última oportunidad de
> cargar las clases o interfaces antes de que falle por un error.

Se trata de una herramienta muy poderosa y muy fácil de configurar. Con ella, te olvidarás de los `include` y de los `require` que pululan por todo el código y que quizá te han costado muchas horas rompiéndote el coco de por qué no se está encontrando este archivo o no se está cargando esta clase.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, en el segundo ejemplo que propones al hacer el include ("dirs.php") forzamente  tengo que  especificarle $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']  o los "../" correspondientes antes de "dirs.php" porque si quiero usar ese archivo en un directorio diferente con un simple include ("dirs.php") no va encontrar el fichero. Me gusta mas la segunda opcion salvo ese detalle.

Comment: Es correcto. A no ser que `dirs.php` se encuentre en otra parte. Lo mejor sería ponerlo en el root y hacer el include como dices: `include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'."/dirs.php");` Aunque en este caso sería mejor usar `include_once` o `require_once`, para que, si ya está incluido en otra parte del proyecto, no lo incluya de nuevo.

Comment: @A.Cedano  una pregunta por que cuando uso include ('Envio.php');  ó
require_once("Envio.php"); , no me funciona pero cuando uso con dirname si me funciona ? , los dos estan en la misma carpeta
 require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Envio.php'; , esto si me funciona

Comment: Buen día @A.Cedano que te parece la alternativa `use` de la respuesta de **AlejoFlorez** es eficiente esa alternativa, tiene alguna desventaja, las haz usado alguna vez, la veo tan sencilla su forma, que se ve agradable. Saludos!

Comment: @IniDesing.com no la he usado nunca, pero la propuesta de Alejo es buena. Según he leído tiene algunas ventajas, como simplicidad (aunque 1º hay que aprender cómo funciona), claridad, evita conflictos entre nombres de archivos/clases/constantes ... cuando se usan otras librerías en el proyecto. Cuando se emplea con clases hay que tener `autoloader`.   Esto aporta la ventaja de que no tienes que hacer `include` de los archivos de las clases para crear instancias de la misma. Cabe decir que `use` trabaja con los espacios de nombres. (Es parecido al `import` de otros lenguajes).

Answer (score 2):

Las rutas en php en un principio son algo complicadas de manejar, y mas aún si no estas usando ningún framework (como laravel por ejemplo) entonces sera un poco mas molestos.

las dos opciones que tu dijes en tu pregunta **incluide** y **require** excepto por un error, en este [enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) podrás saber mas a lo que me refiero, con estos podrás tomar lo que allá en un archivo especificado y lo "pegara" en el tuyo (por decirlo brevemente)

Mientras si lo que quieres es usar las funciones y demás de una clase creada deberás usar la palabra reservada **use**, en este [enlace](http://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php) podrás averiguar mas.

```
use ruta;
```

Lo que hace **use** es buscar desde la raíz de tu proyecto la ruta y nombre de la clase

```
use carpeta\clase;
```

**NOTA IMPORTANTE**

Es importante que recuerdes que las rutas en php siempre que ingreses a una carpeta contenedora deberás poner contra-slash( \ ) hasta encontrar tus archivos

[Aquí](http://php.net/manual/es/wrappers.file.php) podrás ver mas sobre las rutas y archivos

Espero haberte podido ayudar... y suerte con PHP

Saludos!!!

Comment: Interesante método voy a estudiarlo, Saludos!.

Comment: Genial! Me cuentas que tal te va