# Problema con requires y URL

Tags: php

Buenas tardes,

Tengo un problema con el tema de las rutas internas en una plataforma en php.

Este es el mensaje de error:

```
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'http://localhost:8080/CBS/CBSPlatform/html/links.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\CBS\CBSPlatform\dashboard.php on line 34
```

Esto es lo que yo tengo en mi mente y en el código, que seguramente este mal planteado:

Cuando hago los require_once para poner cada parte de la página...

```
<?php require_once($CRDomain . "html/header.php"); ?>
```

... Pongo el $CRDomain que guarda la ruta de la página, para acceder a cada archivo en vez de por assets/css/css.css acceder con http://www.pagina.es/assets/css/css.css. Esto lo hago así para "supuestamente" cuando entra el caso de que por ejemplo, las paginas html para administrar algo esten en administration/ en vez de en la carpeta del index principal. no haya que añadir ../ en cada archivo que se introduzca en esa página.

Volviendo al error de arriba, en e archivo links.php, que supuestamente no encuentra, tengo todos los css ejemplo:

```
<link href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>assets/css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Con el CRDomain tambien para acceder como dije antes.

El caso es que no entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, si alguien pudiese revisar el código para decirme que estoy haciendo mal con las rutas de los archivos lo agradecería mucho.

No sé si me he explicado correctamente, si no decirme y intento aclararlo más de alguna manera.

Un saludo

Comment: ¿Y el código donde incluyes o requieres el archivo **`links.php`** dónde está?  ¿O no lo estás incluyendo realmente y por eso el error?

Comment: <?php require_once($CRDomain . "html/links.php"); ?> con este código requiero el archivo links.php @A.Cedano

Comment: Para depurar haz `echo $CRDomain;` y verifica que esté correcto, que no hayas olvidado o duplicado esto al final `/` o cosas por el estilo. Luego verifica que realmente `links.php`  se encuentra en el directorio que se construye en la combinación de `$CRDomain` con `/html`

Comment: @A.Cedano He comprobado y la ruta es correcta, no hay errores debería de funcionar correctamente. He abierto la ruta independiente y igualmente funciona, pero en el require no funciona si le pongo la variable $CRDomain

Comment: @A.Cedano He encontrado una pequeña solución usando: `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/CBS/CBSPlatform/html/nav/nav.php";` pero a la hora de subir la página al servidor, habría que cambiarlo todo, no? o como afectaría?

Comment: Me confunde que antes tu archivo era `links.php` y ahora se llama `nav.php`. No obstante, para usar una variable la misma debe existir en el contexto, o sea, dentro del mismo código o dentro de otro archivo que se adjunte por medio de `include` o de `require`. Cualquier método que uses funcionará sí y sólo sí las variables que uses existen y apunten hacia rutas y archivos que existan. Te recomiendo que [revises la solución planteada aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967), la cual, creo, podría ser útil para tu caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @Charlie Clewer no se si entendí tu consulta, por favor aclárame en caso que sea conveniente.
Vos necesitas definir unas constantes para luego invocar en el cualquier lugar que necesites de tu estructura de archivos?. De ser así. Yo realizo lo siguiente:

En un archivo Ejemplo: global.php tengo definido

etiqueta php

define("VISTAS","vistas/css");

-Donde vistas es una carpeta y css una sub-carpeta que contiene a su ves varias carpetas o archivos que vas a requerir en otros archivos-

Este archivo lo requiero en el index principal o donde utilice estas constantes definidas.

Ejemplo: index.php

comienzo etiqueta php

require_once "global.php";

comienzo etiqueta html

etiqueta php

require_once (VISTAS . "/css.css");

require_once (VISTAS . "/style.css");

cierre php

continua codigo html

Aclarando. Sería, tener un archivo que estén definidas las rutas, luego invocas ese archivo y requerís tus parámetros definidos. 
Ante cualquier duda estoy atento. Saludos. Espero ser de ayuda.-

Answer (score 1):

El error se da porque en PHP, include, require y require_once  hacen referencia a la ruta absoluta en el servidor, no a un URL, digamos entonces que su uso no está correctamente aplicado aquí,para lo que se requiere deberían existir, en todo caso, 2 variables:

```
$CRDomain = 'http://localhost:8080/CBS/CBSPlatform/';
$AbsRoute = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\CBS\CBSPlatform\';
```

De este modo podrías llamar:

```
<?php require_once($AbsRoute . "html/header.php"); ?>
```

Y utilizar:

```
<link href="<?php echo $CRDomain; ?>assets/css/mainstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Para los assets accesibles desde la URL, de este modo sería una mejor aplicación.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Funciona porque es una variable global que devuelve el directorio raíz de documentos del servidor en el cual se está ejecutando el script actual, según está definida en el archivo de configuración del servidor, pero toda vez estén definidas e incluidas las variables de arriba, también funcionará.