# Problemas al incluir archivos en servidor de producción

Tags: php

Amigos, estoy teniendo un problema que ya me está dando dolor de cabeza. Tengo un proyecto que su estructura es de la siguiente manera (Localhost XAMP):

htttp://localhost/miproyecto
 En la raiz tengo estas carpetas:

```
-js
 --jssistema.js
 -controladores
 --controladores.php
 --controlador1.php
 --controlador2.php
 --controlador3.php

 -modelos
 --modelos.php
 --modelo1.php
 --modelo2.php
 --modelo3.php

 -plantillas
 --ajax.php
 --plantilla.php
```

El archivo **controladores.php** tiene esto:

```
require_once '../controladores/controlador1.php';
require_once '../controladores/controlador2.php';
require_once '../controladores/controlador3.php';
```

El archivo **modelos.php** tiene esto:

```
require_once '../modelos/modelo1.php';
require_once '../modelos/modelo2.php';
require_once '../modelos/modelo3.php';
```

El archivo **plantilla.php** tiene esto:

```
require_once 'controladores/controladores.php';
require_once 'modelos/modelos.php';
```

El archivo jssistema.js lo utilizo para hacer login al sistema, también hago "delete", es decir, elimino registros de unas tablas con ajax todo funciona correctamente, entre otras cosas dinámicas. Todo lo envía a **ajax.php** que está más o menos así:

```
require '../controladores/controladores.php';
require '../modelos/modelos.php';
```

Esto funciona todo muy bien en localhost (Windows + XAMP), pero cuando cargo el proyecto al sevidor (linux amazon ami), mis includes están incorrectos, es decir, en **ajax.php** tengo que cambiar las rutas de los archivos a incluir pues supongo que están fuera de contexto (lo mismo en el archivo controladores.php y modelos.php) Algo así:

```
require_once 'controladores/controladores.php';
require_once 'modelos/modelos.php';
```

Obvio al hacer el cambio anterior, el jssistema.js funciona, pero ya el proyecto en general deja de funcionar pues no encuentra los archivos.

Lo que busco es que si me pueden ayduar a incluir todos mis archivos desde URLs absolutas para que no tenga problemas con los includs locales ni foráneos :(

Espero haberme explicado.

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Puedes definir las rutas de tus directorios, y luego usar esas constantes. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3644687/5587982).

Comment: Estoy intentando hacer algo así: define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));   debido a la estructura de mi proyecto ¿En donde es correcto definir la constante? Gracias.

Comment: Como bien se explica en el enlace, puedes tener todas las constantes en un archivo, por ejemplo:  `config.php` y luego requieres ese archivo en las diferentes partes del programa donde necesites incluir algo.

Comment: [Aquí tienes otro ejemplo (ver en el apartado **Otra posibilidad**)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967)  es algo parecido a lo anterior, pero las explicaciones están en castellano.

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, voy a revisarlo detenidamente.

Comment: `__DIR__` contiene la ruta de la carpeta donde está el archivo desde donde se lo consulta, el primer require de `controladores.php` puede ser escrito como `require_once __DIR__ . '/controlador1.php';` (lo va a incluir desde esa misma carpeta)

Comment: Gracias a ambos, apliqué las sugerencias y quedó resuelto, infinitamente gracias.