# Redirección al directorio raiz de un sitio web, independientemente del directorio en el que se encuentre el script

Tags: php, redirección

En un fichero .php tengo declarada la constante:

`define('login_location', $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].'/app/login.php');`

Y cuando lo llamo desde otro fichero, dentro de un subdirectorio del raiz, por ejemplo, /sub/, si hago un:

`require_once '../fichero.php'; //Es donde está definida la constante.
 header('Location: '.login_location);`

Esto me lleva a: directorio_raiz / sub / directorio_raiz / app / login.php

Y yo quiero que me lleve a: directorio_raiz / app / login.php

Este sería un ejemplo de directorio:

```
root

-file_directory_constant_decalarated.php

-/app/login.php

-/sub/file_with_header_location.php
```

Comment: No entiendo lo que explicas en la pregunta, es confuso. ¿Si haces un `echo login_location;` ¿qué sale en pantalla? Yo en tu caso usaría un archivo de constantes donde tendría declaradas todas mis rutas, incluiría ese archivo y usaría las rutas de forma natural sin más complicaciones. Sería como [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967), si lees el apartado ***Otra posibilidad***.

Comment: @A.Cedano He modificado la pregunta y he puesto un ejemplo de directorio raiz. Si se hiciera un echo de esa variable con la ruta, saldría por pantalla root/app/login.php pero cuando lo incluyo en el header, no lo hace bien y es como si esa ruta estuviera dentro de /sub/ y no es asi.

Comment: Pero para hacer referencia al root debes usar `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, prueba a definir la constante así: **`define('login_location', $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/app/login.php');`**

Comment: @A.Cedano estaríamos en las mismas no?, si utilizo esa constante dentro del subdirectorio, el header location me llevará a root/sub/var/www/webpage...

Comment: ¿Lo probaste? ¿Y el `echo login_location;` donde lo hiciste, supongo que en el archivo donde haces la redirección?  ¿No tendrás esa constante declarada otra vez en otro archivo que incluyes?

Comment: Prueba también de este modo: `define('ROOT_PATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/');
define('APP_PATH', ROOT_PATH.'app/'); define('FILE_LOGIN', APP_PATH.'login.php/');` y luego, incluyes el archivo con las constantes y pones el location así: `header('Location: '.FILE_LOGIN);`  Si así no funciona, dime lo que imprime un `echo FILE_LOGIN;` hecho en el archivo donde haces la redirección. Es extraño que no funcione así.