# HTTP ERROR 500 La página ... no puede procesar esta solicitud ahora

Tags: php, html5, laravel-5, hosting

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Muy Buenas a todos!
Tengo este problema que me esta volviendo loco.
Se trata de un proyecto que he subido a Hostalia desde de Git.
Bueno, después de pasar días intentando configurar mi index.php no he logrado nada de nada.

La idea es:

```
Dentro de Hostalia;
proyecto.com -> index.php
proyecto -> app,bootstrap, config, database...
```

En el archivo Index.php tengo:

```
require __DIR__.'/../proyecto/vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../proyecto/bootstrap/app.php';

$app->bind('path.public', function() {
    return __DIR__.'/proyecto/public';
});
```

Por favor si alguien me puede ayudar estaria super agradecido y que conste que no he encontrado ninguna solución para este problema aún que error 500 existen miles.

Desde luego Gracias!

> Error en LOG del Host:
>
> [Mon Apr 08 18:28:22.968778 2019] [fcgid:warn]
>   [pid ...:tid ...] [client ...] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: 
>   require(/var/www/vhosts/...servicio-online.net/httpdocs/../proyecto/vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /var/www/vhosts/...servicio-online.net/httpdocs/index.php on line 24

Supongo que a lo que referias era la imagen de los directorios del servidor.
Te comento, ahora mismo me sale este error:

```js
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Application' not found in /var/www/vhosts/....servicio-online.net/proyecto.com/proyecto/bootstrap/app.php:14 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/38949654.servicio-online.net/proyecto.com/index.php(39): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/38949654.servicio-online.net/proyecto.com/proyecto/bootstrap/app.php on line 14
```

Y lo que he hecho fue llama con `$ruta=__DIR__."/proyecto/vendor/autoload.php";
echo $ruta;` y para la ruta **Bootstrap/app.php**, `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/proyecto/bootstrap/app.php';`.

[image: Esta es la dirección del 'autoload.php']

[image: Esta es la dirección del index.php]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Revisa el log de errores. Es difícil decirte así sin más dónde está el problema, puesto que incluyes archivos de otras partes, etc.

Comment: Quizás con este error del Log del Host podréis ver mejor el problema. Gracias!

Comment: El error es claro: *`failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/...servicio-online.net/httpdocs/index.php on line 24`*  indica que el archivo que estás intentando llamar en la línea 24 de `index.php` no está siendo encontrado. Eso suele ocurrir cuando tienes mal ubicados los archivos o las librerías. ¿Cuál es la línea 24 de tu `index.php`?  Ubica la ruta absoluta de ese archivo y prueba poniendo la ruta absoluta, solamente para depurar el error, luego tendrás que ver la forma de combinar `__DIR__` con el dato correcto según tengas organizadas las carpetas.

Comment: Perdoname por mi insistencia, y es que la línea 24 es la referida arriba <require __DIR__.'/../proyecto/vendor/autoload.php';>. Lo cambie de diversas maneras y sin resultado positivo. Si puedes ser un pelín más claro en cuanto a poner rutas absolutas te lo agradezco. E se for posible un ejemplo mejor. Gracias!

Comment: Con **ruta absoluta** me refiero a que en vez de usar `__DIR__`,  pongas la ruta completa donde se encuentra el archivo `autoload.php`, por ejemplo: `require 'car/pe/tas/proyecto/vendor/autoload.php';` El problema es que al usar `__DIR__` no te está construyendo la ruta donde el archivo está realmente. Una forma sencilla de probarlo es haciendo algo así: `$ruta=__DIR__."/../proyecto/vendor/autoload.php";` y luego imprimes lo que eso produce: `echo `$ruta;` si comparas la salida del `echo` verás que no se está construyendo realmente la ruta donde se encuentra `autoload.php` sino otra cosa.

Comment: Verdad que haciendo un "echo" me imprime las rutas pero aún cambiandolas por rutas absolutas no logro el resultado esperado. Tffff..

Comment: A. Cedano. Seguiré intentando. Ya subiré futuros resultados.

Comment: Todavía nada. He probado con **ruta absoluta** y me pasa el mismo error.

Comment: Creo que no me has entendido. Tu error es que el archivo no se encuentra en la ruta que estás poniendo. Hagamos una cosa, muestra una imagen de tu árbol de directorios e indícanos dónde está el archivo autoload y dónde está el script que presentas en la pregunta.

Comment: Por cierto, me dejaba algo sin explicar. He añadido un comando **Artisan** en rutas: `Route::get('/optimize', function() { $exitCode = Artisan::call('optimize'); return '
Reoptimized class loader'; }); ` y no a cambiado nada.

Comment: A ver, si no muestras la ruta donde está `autoload.php` que es el archivo que está dando problemas, será imposible indicarte la forma correcta de incluir ese archivo. También te pedí que hicieras algo así: `$ruta=__DIR__."/../proyecto/vendor/autoload.php";` y luego que hagas `echo $ruta;` y mostraras lo que imprime ese `echo`. Son cosas básicas de depuración que deberías aprender: si algo no funciona, muéstralo por  pantalla y compáralo con la realidad.

Comment: Primero la estructura que muestas es `example.com/proyecto/public/` 2 directorios arriba de la raiz y  por lo que veo intentas acceder a example.com/proyecto/. Cuando deve ser example.com/proyecto/public/ tambien se te agradece colocar la estructura de carpetas. Que en tu imagen no se ve casi nada

Comment: `proyecto/vendor/autoload.php` esta es la ruta. `index.php` y `proyecto` están dentro de la carpeta **proyecto.com**. y si hice `$ruta=__DIR__."/proyecto/vendor/autoload.php";`. Está comentada más a bajo.

Comment: ok! intentaré ser más preciso.

Comment: Si no muestras las rutas completas no podremos ayudarte. No sé por qué te complicas tanto. Muestra en una imagen dónde está `autoload.php` y dónde está `index.php`

Comment: Siento haber tardado! Tenia compromiso.

Comment: @QueopiusASantos el error es claro, PHP no encuentra el archivo en la ruta que estás agregando. Creó que deberías chequear la siguiente pregunta con su respectiva respuestas https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91530/como-manejar-rutas-de-archivos-php  Saludos!

Comment: El error es claro, estoy de acuerdo! pero, la solución no la acabo de ver.. é probado de todo @IniDesing y nada. Os pido perdón por las molestias que causo debido a mi poca experiencia con php. Déjame un ejemplo de como solventar este problema porfavor!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no se como funciona el `host` pero parece ser el .htaccess ya no le da privilegio de acceder, mejor crea un subdominio, es decir una carpeta,`/public_html/nuevacarpeta`
aqui mediante el `FTP` subes todo tu proyecto y el la catpeta raiz creas index.php o .html `/public_html/index.php` haces un autoredirect a `www.dominio.com/nuevacarpeta/public`

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" CONTENT="0;URL=http://www.tudominio.com/nuevacarpeta/public">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**incluye todo el vendor y .env**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Muestra toda la información, por defecto INFO_ALL
phpinfo();

// Muestra solamente la información de los módulos.
// phpinfo(8) hace exactamente lo mismo.
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);

?>
```

verifique la versión de PHP en el localhost de su computador y la versión de PHP en el servidor, ya que el error puede ser la versión de PHP que esta utilizando en el servido es incompatible

**Versión de php incompatible con la programación**
Es bastante común ver errores 500 cuando una pagina **ha sido programada para php 5.6 o inferior, y se instala la versión php 7.0 o superior**. En estos casos, la solución es sencilla, Basta con volver a la version 5.6 y el error se soluciona. También es indicativo que tu programación debe ser revisada para que pueda ser funcionar en el ultima versión de php y así disfrutar de las mejoras de velocidad, rendimiento y seguridad.

otra soluccion seria que suba todos los archivos desde FTP utilizando filezilla, ya que Cpane a la hora de descomprimir algunos archivos se puede daña

Comment: La versión de mi localhost es: **PHP 7.2.4 (cli)** y la del servidor Hosting es **7.2**. Y ahora me sale esto: `/var/www/vhosts/....servicio-online.net/proyecto.com/proyecto/vendor/autoload.php`. Teniendo en cuanta que hago la llamada con `$ruta=__DIR__."/proyecto/vendor/autoload.php";
echo $ruta;` si me puedes ayudar estaré muy agradecido!

Comment: Por cierto he subido mis archivos con **Git**.

Comment: la version de localhost  es superio en el hosting, lo que tiene que hace es instalar la version de PHP sea igual o inferio en el hosting, en el hosting deber ser asi 7.2.0 =>7.2.4, ya que ese .4 puede genera el error