# Error al abrir archivo Vendor/autoload.php de Composer

Tags: php, phpmailer, composer

Os pido ayuda por si alguien puede darme alguna pista de lo que está pasando aquí. Tengo un fichero PHP para registrase un nuevo usuario donde envío un email con PHPMailer:

```
<?php
    require_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
```

El email lo manda sin problemas. Desde el email hay una url para confirmar registro que me lleva de nuevo a la web. Aquí tengo otro archivo PHP que intenta mandar un email de bienvenida. El modo de llamar a PHPMailer es exactamente igual que el fichero anterior y está dentro de la misma ruta pero me da error:

```
 Failed opening required '../vendor/autoload.php' 
 (include_path='.:/usr/local/php71/pear')
```

Alguna idea de por qué sucede esto? Añado la ruta de los ficheros:

```
Ruta principal 
  ->Vendor
  ->php
      ->nuevoRegistro.php (envia el email sin problema)
      ->activarUsuario.php (error al abrir vendor/autoload.php)
  ->html
      ->topnav.html (llama a activarUsuario.php)
         <ul class="nav">
           <?php
               if(isset($_GET['key'])){

    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/activarUsuario.php');
          }
  ->js
      ->registro.js (llama a nuevoRegistro.php)
           function nuevoRegistro(){ 
             $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {user: user, pass: pass},
                url: '../php/nuevoRegistro.php',
                success: function(data) {
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: O sea, ¿los dos scripts PHP están exactamente en la misma ruta? ¿Segura, segura? ¿Podrías por favor [edit] la pregunta y poner la parte de ambos scripts donde haces el require así como la URL que llega al email (puedes disimular el dominio a fines de confidencialidad)?

Comment: He añadido la ruta tal y como tengo los ficheros y desde donde se llaman. Ruta principal: carpeta vendor, carpeta php, carpeta html y carpeta js

Comment: Dijiste que el 1er email tiene una URL que enlaza a `activarUsuario.php`, ¿cómo es esa ruta en el email?  Compárala con la ruta con la que accedes a `nuevoRegistro.php` en el navegador, ¿son **exactamente iguales**?

Comment: Y, ¿cómo es el código Javascript que llama a `nuevoRegistro.php`? Muestra tu contexto completo con los fragmentos de código implicados para que podamos ayudarte. Al hacer la mención sobre JS no sé si el fichero es llamado desde JS o es una URL que va en el texto del email ¿?

Comment: puede ser por $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ??

Comment: Sí, casi seguro que es eso. Prueba poniendo la ruta **completa y correcta**. Luego te sugiero algo para evitar estos líos de rutas.

Comment: Sí, casi seguro que es eso. Prueba poniendo la ruta **completa y correcta**.  Otra forma de depurar sería haciendo un `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/activarUsuario.php'` y verificando si es efectivamente la ruta correcta... Luego te sugiero algo para evitar estos líos de rutas.

Comment: Efectivamente, el error esta en el document_root, me devuelve 
/home/tripfam/public_html. Si pongo la ruta completa de la url de mi web no me da ese error (aunque tampoco me envia el email pero ese será otro error..)

Comment: Si me puedes hacer alguna recomendación sobre cómo debo incluir la ruta te lo agradezco

Comment: La sugerencia es muy simple, creas un archivo con constantes que apunten a todas tus rutas e incluyes ese archivo donde necesites usar rutas y haces uso de la constante de la ruta. Está explicado en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967) en el apartado titulado **Otra posibilidad**. Si observas bien, se van reutilizando las constantes en forma jerárquica, lo cual permite hacer cualquier cambio de ruta sin ningún trauma, lo único que hay que cambiar es la constante respectiva a esa ruta y nada más en todo el proyecto.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda!! Así lo haré ;)