# pasar de un directorio a otro en php

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente inconveniente con los archivos que se cargan con require_once desde otra dirección, el archivo data/editproductoc.php necesita cargar el header que esta en el directorio static/header.php,  la raiz **es la carpeta dcginv**. Se carga sin los archivos del header o el footer que contienen los css y js adjunto el codigo. Desde ya muchas Gracias

```
<?php
session_start();
if (@!$_SESSION['user']) {
    header("Location:index.php");
} elseif ($_SESSION['rol'] == 2) {

    require_once '../static/header.php';
}
<?
```

....

```
   <?php

require_once '../static/footer.php';

?>

//Este es el codigo que va en el archivo data/editproductoc.php. solo carga el contenido html
```

Comment: No me queda del todo claro, lo que quieres es cargar el header y el footer a este fichero php, no?
y el header y el footer se encuntran en otras carpetas, no?

Comment: Correcto, no me funciona solo carga el contenido html y ya cambie como se muestra a ../static/header.php, se supone que me voy hacia atrás un directorio con .. y luego coloco el directorio static/header.php. El directorio raiz es dcginv

Comment: vale, yo no suelo usar el require_once para insertar un fichero en otro, suelo usar el include. Otra cosa puedes mostrar el código de los ficheros que quieres añadir?

Comment: Lo probe con include y me da el mismo resultado. el contenido luego es solo un formulario con  inputs y buton html, que lo muestra pero sin el formato de los css que es boostrap

Comment: Vale  entonces tu problema esque incluye el contenido de los ficheros pero sin su css. Para eso tienes que poner el css (si esque lo tienes interno en esos ficheros) en un fichero css y que el que va a incluirlos utilice este fichero. Nosé si me entiendes o te estoy liando aun más

Comment: Si sigues sin entender lo que te digo, dimelo y te pongo un ejemplo. :D

Comment: Si pero me estaría creando codigo adicional (repetido para una o dos paginas) y son bastantes archivos los de boostrap más los js

Comment: Me imagino que el css de boostrap los tienes en un fichero css y en el header y el footer los llamas, lo que te digo yo es que no llames al cod de boostrap ahi sino en el index (llamemoslo index al archivo que los incluye) y de esta manera te funcionará

Comment: Y si a parte tienetes una etiqueta style en esos ficheros con sus códigos de css simplemente traladalos a un archivo de css existente o crea otros. Nosé si el código de css que tienes en los ficheros es redundante o no, de serlo llama al  css que haga el mismo efecto.

Comment: Para no vivir liado con las rutas, puedes crear constantes de cada ruta en un archivo (que se podría llamar por ejemplo `dirs.php`) y luego usar esas constantes. De ese modo, si alguna ruta cambia, sólo la cambias en `dirs.php` y no tendrías que cambiar archivo por archivo. Revisa [esta respuesta (sobre todo el apartado titulado ***«Otra posibilidad»***)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967) donde explico mejor de qué se trata.

Comment: Vi tu comentario  A. Cedano y esta bueno en mi caso deberia crear dirs.php en la carpeta dcginv que es la raiz

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a utilizar las constantes predefinidas de PHP.

Prueba con `<?php require_once(__dir__ . '../static/header.php');
...
?>`

Tienes más información [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php)