# Método que requiere de otra clase da error dependiendo del archivo del que se llama

Tags: php, poo

Tengo una clase Artículo con una función __construct que contiene un include:

```
class Articulo{
private $imagen = '';
private $texto = '';
private $titulo = '';
private $id;

private $db;
private $conexion;

function __construct(){
    include 'conexion/Conexion.php';
    $db = new Conexion;
    $this->conexion = $db->connect();
}
```

Pues dependiendo desde dónde llame a esa función da error de localización o no. Si llamo desde index.php o desde admin.php no hay problema ninguno. Pero cuando llamo desde sem-articulo me dice:  include(conexion/Conexion.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
[image: Árbol de contenido]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que en el include usas rutas relativas y para que funcione en sub-carpetas tienes que usar absolutas.
Algo asi:

```
class Articulo{
private $imagen = '';
private $texto = '';
private $titulo = '';
private $id;

private $db;
private $conexion;

function __construct(){
    $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $path .= 'conexion/Conexion.php';
    include_once($path);
    $db = new Conexion;
    $this->conexion = $db->connect();
}
```

Comment: Si, en mi respuesta he indicado una solución básica, pero esta es una solución más adecuada

Comment: Otra opción interesante es definir constantes para las rutas, sobre todo en proyectos grandes ([Ver el apartado **Otra posibilidad** de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967)). Así, si alguna ruta cambia, sólo hay que cambiar el valor en la constante.

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias a todos! En cuanto a lo que comentas @A. Cedano, me lo había planteado. Pero, al declarar una constante por ejemplo, en el archivo config, no tendría el mismo problema al llamar a config.php?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía no entendí la duda sobre config ¿? Las constantes definirían rutas, las cuales usarías luego de haber incluido el archivo que las contiene. No conviene que esas rutas se declaren en ningún otro archivo, sino en uno dedicado a ellas, sobre todo para no estar incluyendo archivos grandes para este uso.

Answer (score 2):

Fijate que semi-articulo se encuentra ubicado en la carpeta controler. Por tanto, si haces un include desde esa ubicación a Conexión.php deberás hacer un include este estilo:

```
include '../conexion/Conexion.php';
```

Mi recomendación personal es que no hagas un include dentro de un constructor.