# msql_query a msqli_query no encuentra el usuario

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql

He actualizado una página web que funcionaba con **PHP** de una versión muy antigua, al actualizar el hosting he tenido que actualizar también los comandos de **PHP Query** de **MySQL** a **MySQLi**, el caso es que no entiendo por qué no me devuelve ninguna fila al ejecutar esta función. La tabla está bien y la base de datos conecta correctamente.

Creo que el problema es `if(mysqli_num_rows($result))` pero no soy capaz de solucionarlo.

```
require('../files/bd.php'); 
class cpm {
    var $userid = '';
    var $useremail = '';        
    var $messages = array();    
    var $receivers = array();
    var $dateformat = '';   


    function cpm($user,$date="d.m.Y - H:i") {

    $this->userid = $user; 
    $this->dateformat = $date;
    $this->useremail = $this->getemail($this->userid);
    $this->getMessageReceivers();
    }

    function getemail($userid) {
    $sql = "SELECT Email FROM mentor2009 WHERE `orden` = '".$userid."' LIMIT 1";    

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    // Check if there is someone with this id

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
        // if yes get his username
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        return $row[0];
    } else {
        // if not, name him Unknown
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

Archivo **bd.php**:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxx");
mysqli_set_charset("utf8", $link);
```

Ruta de los archivos:

La base de datos esta aqui : public_html >files > bd.php la clase donde llamo al requiere está aqui: public_html >pms > cpm.class.php

Comment: Hola Victor, podrías indicar que versión de PHP usabas y cuál usas ahora. Esto podría ayudar a detectar si hay alguna incompatibilidad.

Comment: Puede haber un error de sintaxis en tu consulta, para descartarlo puedes hacer algo así: `if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {  //aquí el bloque que lee los datos if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) { //etc } else { return "Error: {mysqli_error($link)}"; }` Prueba así y dinos qué error muestra.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @A.Cedano, revisé la documentación y parece que usas correctamente el estilo por procedimientos. En adición puedes usar:

`var_dump($result);`
`exit();`

Para obtener que valor hay detrás de la consulta.

Comment: Ya solo por preguntar, ` $this->userid = $user; ` no será `$user` el objeto user y no el userId ?

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por la rapida respuesta , voy a probar vuestras propuestas y os digo algo. La versión PHP actual es PHP 5.6.40, la anterior no puedo averiguarlo porque no tengo control sobre el hosting original de la web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te animo a escribir un código controlado que prevea todas las eventualidades posibles.

En tu caso hay dos eventualidades que se escapan y que no controlas de ningún modo:

1. La conexión podría falla
2. La consulta podría fallar

En este caso ambas cosas se controlan y el código te informará adecuadamente de lo que ocurre:

```
function getemail($userid) {
    if ($link) {
        $sql = "SELECT Email FROM mentor2009 WHERE `orden` = '".$userid."' LIMIT 1";    
        if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
            // Check if there is someone with this id
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
                // if yes get his username
                $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
                return $row[0];
            } else {
                // if not, name him Unknown
                $output="Unknown";
            }
        } else {
            #Esto es sólo para depuración. No conviene mostrar errores internos de la BD
            #Cambia luego mysqli_error($link) por un error personalizado si quieres
            $output= "Error en la consulta: {mysqli_error($link)}";
        }
    }else{
        $output= "No hay conexion";
    }
    return $output;
}
```

---

## NOTAS

1. Si en la tabla la columna `orden` es numérica, la consulta debe ser escrita así sin más, no tienes que usar comillas simples y la variable puede ir dentro de la cadena si ésta empieza y termina por comillas dobles: `$sql="SELECT Email FROM mentor2009 WHERE` orden `= $userid LIMIT 1";`
2. Considera el uso de consultas preparadas. Tu actual código es vulnerable a ataques de *Inyección SQL*. Cuando puedas lee sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta tan completa voy a probarlo y comento los resultados

Comment: El problema está en if ($link) , siempre da ERROR.

Comment: He añadido el contenido del archivo bd.php en la pregunta para ampliar la información por si hay algo incorrecto

Comment: @VíctorCalderón puede que la ruta del require no sea correcta: `require('../files/bd.php'); ` o que la conexión no se está creando porque las credenciales que le pasas no son correctas. Pon una prueba de la conexión para descartar eso, emitiendo un mensaje de error.

Comment: El require debe estar correcto porque cuando pongo ../../files/bd,php me da un fatal error y me pide  corregirlo

Comment: @VíctorCalderón pero si da error en el `else` de $link significa que la conexión no se está creando bien por algún motivo. Para determinarlo puedes poner la parte del `else` de este modo:  `$output= "No hay conexion. Error: {mysqli_connect_error()}";`

Comment: Ya he encontrado el problema, no hace bien el require al archivo de bd.php, en la clase cpm.php al poner el require no funciona, por eso $link da siempre nulo, lo he solucionado incluyendo el msqli_connect dentro de cada función de la clase cpm.php, alguna idea de por qué el require  no funciona?

Comment: @VíctorCalderón si colocas en la pregunta la estructura de directorios que tienes podré decirte por qué no funciona. Por otra parte te aconsejaría que implementes una *política de inclusiones*  por llamarle de algún modo, se trata de crear constantes que apunten a ese tipo de recursos que usas mucho y luego usarías esas constantes para hacer los `require` lo s `include`, etc. Si te interesa, puedes leer [esta respuesta, en el apartado **Otra posibilidad**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).

Comment: La base de datos esta aqui  :                                                          public_html >files > bd.php                                                                               la clase donde llamo al requiere está aqui:                                                   public_html >pms > cpm.class.php

Answer (score 0):

Haciendo una observación a tu código, veo que tienes esto:

```
 if(mysqli_num_rows($result)) {
```

Ese if no te va a entrar porque según la documentación `PHP` sobre la función [mysqli_num_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) es que dicha función retorna un numero de filas según la SQL, por lo tanto un numero entero.

Al poner el `if(...)` de esa maneras esperas un boleean, (TRUE o FALSE).

Para que ese `if` se ha correcta puedes ponerlo de esta manera:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
```

o

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
```

Dependiendo del numero de filas que pueda devolver tu `query`

Tu ejemplo completo quedaría así:

```
require('../files/bd.php'); 
class cpm {
    var $userid = '';
    var $useremail = '';        
    var $messages = array();    
    var $receivers = array();
    var $dateformat = '';   


    function cpm($user,$date="d.m.Y - H:i") {

    $this->userid = $user; 
    $this->dateformat = $date;
    $this->useremail = $this->getemail($this->userid);
    $this->getMessageReceivers();
    }

    function getemail($userid) {
    $sql = "SELECT Email FROM mentor2009 WHERE `orden` = '".$userid."' LIMIT 1";    

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    // Check if there is someone with this id

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
        // if yes get his username
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        return $row[0];
    } else {
        // if not, name him Unknown
        return "Unknown";
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lamentablemente no funciona en ninguno de los dos casos, si pongo  > 0 no devuelve Uknown y si lo pongo simplemente como mysqli_num_rows($result) tampoco devuelve ningún resultado. He realizado las consultas en phpmyadmin directamente y la base de datos me devuelve varios resultados, el problema claramente está en  (mysqli_num_rows($result)

Comment: Buenas Mario, lo que comentas es erroneo. Internamente un booleano, es un 0  un 1, si 0 (false), no entrara en el if, si es 1 o distinto de 0, entrara en el if. Por lo que @VíctorCalderón tienes esa linea bien y no necesitarias cambiarla