# Problema con header("Location:index.php)

Tags: php, php7

Hola a todos los de la comunidad.

Acudo a ustedes por que tengo un problema con header:Location, resulta que tengo el siguiente sitio:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resulta que cuando agrego una categoría nueva la debe guardar en la BD y enviarme nuevamente a mi index.php, resulta que no pasa eso, pasa lo sgte:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver, en vez de enviarme al directorio raiz que es donde esta index.php, lo busca en la carpeta de includes, se que funciona por que tengo una funcion que valida que la session este iniciada con el objetivo de evitar que por la caja de dirección del navegador entren alguna otra pagina de mi sitio y cuando valida que la session no está iniciada me manda otra vez al index, pero en este caso no funciona.

Este es el codigo que uso:

```html
<?php
 if(isset($_POST)){
  //Conexion a la BD
  require_once 'conexion.php';
  $nombre = isset($_POST['nombre']) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['nombre']) : false;
  
  //Array de errores
  $errores = array();
  
  //Validar los datos antes de guardarlos en la BD
  //Validar campo nombre
  if(!empty($nombre) && !is_numeric($nombre) && !preg_match("/[0-9]/", $nombre)){
   $nombre_validado = true;
  } else {
   $nombre_validado = false;
   $errores['nombre'] = "El nombre no es valido";
  }
 }
 if(count($errores) == 0){
  $sql = "INSERT INTO categorias VALUES (null, '$nombre')";
  $guardar = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 }
 header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

Agradeceria mucho la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: puede ser que te falten los puntos header("location: ../index.php"); los puntos dependiendo que tan lejos este del directorio raiz por ejemplo header("location: ../../login.php"); si esta dos carpetas dentro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que no te de problemas podrías crear una variable global con la url:

```
define('url_base', '//'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/proyectophp/');
```

y ponerla en el header:

```
header('Location: '.url_base.'index.php');
```

En vez de redireccionar simplemente como:

```
index.php
```

Sería como:

```
http://localhost/proyectophp/index.php
```

De esta manera obtienes una ruta absoluta y uno se complica menos.

Ahora si debería de llevarte al index, incluyendo el nombre de la carpeta de proyecto en la variable global, y si es un dominio le quitas el nombre "proyectophp" A la variable global y listo.

Comment: Gracias, mañana intento esta solución y te cuento

Comment: Hola, sigue sin funcionar, el problema es que no sale del nivel includes ni poniendo la direccion completa, queda de la siguiente manera:
http://localhost/proyectophp/includes/localhost/proyectophp/index.php

Comment: @sebastianvalencia el problema persiste quizá debido al uso de `SERVER_NAME`, puede que no sea lo más adecuado para esto. Revisa mi sugerencia en el apartado **Otra posibilidad** dado en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967). Puedes hacer algo así, basándote en `DOCUMENT_ROOT`. Te aconsejo que crees una especie de jerarquía de rutas, de modo que las puedas usar de forma independiente cada una.

Comment: Has probado de la siguiente manera? (Aclaro que no se como es tu directorio raiz del proyecto, podrias tambien enviar una foto de como esta confromado todo el directorio del protecto?)   header('Location: http://localhost/proyectophp/index.php');

Comment: Les agradezco a todos la ayuda que me han dado, pude solucionar el problema anteponiendo al nombre del directorio ../ tal como me dijo @A. Cedano, por cierto es muy interesante la información sobre el manejo de directorios, me gustaria contar con mas info sobre este tema ya que no entendí muy bien lo que lei.

Comment: @sebastianvalencia ¿qué fue lo que no entendiste exactamente? En la respuesta referida se explicaba una forma de mantener los directorios en un archivo `dirs.php` mediante constantes e incluir ese archivo donde hiciera falta y usar las constantes para referirse a los directorios.

Comment: mejor dicho, como puedo usar ese archivo, por ejemplo en mi index???, solo lo incluyo con include y el archivo dirs.php pongo todas las direcciones de los archivos que voy a usar???

Answer (score 2):

Pude resolver mi problema gracias a las sugerencias que me dieron, lo que me tocó hacer fue reiniciar mi servidor y escribir la instrucción header de la siguiente manera:

```
header("Location:../index.php);
```

una vez se reinicio el server y actualize mi proyecto funcionó, me redirigió a mi index.php que está en el directorio raíz, gracias a @A. Cedano que me compartió un hilo explicando sobre el manejo de directorios.