# Dudas sobre Include en PHP (css dentro del incluido)

Tags: php, directorioactivo

Estoy utilizando la funcion include de php para incluir el footer a mi index, footer.php esta en el fichero "footer". El include, toma como directorio padre el del archivo donde es invocado, osea que en mi index al hacer el include, es como que footer.php esta al mismo nivel que index.php. Por ende, al llamar la hoja de estilos tengo que llamarla a la siguiente ruta "footer/style_header.css".
Ahora mi duda es, hay alguna manera de que pueda llamar a la hoja de estilos sin hacer eso? Se me ocurrio hacer alguna funcion tipo getStylesheet() pero creo que debe haber algo mas simple.

[image: Estructura de fichero]

Esta es la estructura de ficheros, desde en footer.php tengo esta linea de link a hoja de estilos:

```css
<link rel="stylesheet" href="footer/style_footer.css">
```

Lo que me gustaria es que sea algo como href="style_footer.css" y listo digamos, mas simple y facil de entender

Comment: Buenas como va, podrías editar la pregunta y subir la parte del código que necesitas "optimizar" junto con la estructura de las carpetas para que sea mas fácil darte una respuesta

Comment: Lo más simple que hay es definir constantes con las rutas y subrutas de tus archivos a incluir y luego usar esas constantes en todo el proyecto. Así, si tienes que cambiar un archivo puedes hacerlo sin ningún problema, solamente tendrías que cambiar la ruta en la constante y listo. [Mira esta respuesta, en el apartado titulado **Otra posibilidad**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967). Si observas, para flexibilizar, se crea una constante por cada carpeta, desde la carpeta raíz hasta las sub-carpetas, esto te permitirá manejar sin problemas los include en cualquier contexto.