# ¿Por que Apache no mapea mi archivo php?

Tags: php, apache, aplicación-web, codificación, opera

Sucede que estoy haciendo un programa MVC en php y me sale el siguiente error:

**Warning: require_once(../app/contoladores/Paginas.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\librerias\Core.php on line 32**

**Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../app/contoladores/Paginas.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\librerias\Core.php on line 32**

En mi aplicación uso el código adecuado, de hecho si esta tomando el nombre de mi archivo .php pero por alguna extraña razón no me arroja que no existe

Anexo Código y framework:

```
class Core{

protected $controladorActual = 'paginas';

protected $metodoActual = 'index';

protected $parametros = [];

//Constructor
public function __construct()
{
    //print_r($this->getURL());
    $url = $this->getURL();

    //buscar en controladores si el controlador existe
    if(file_exists('../app/controladores/'.ucwords($url[0]).'.php')){
        //Si existe se entrega como controlador por defecto
        $this->controladorActual = ucwords($url[0]);
        //unset
        unset($url[0]);
    }

    //requerir el controlador
    require_once '../app/contoladores/'.ucwords($this->controladorActual).'.php';
    $this->controladorActual = new $this->contoladorActual;
}

public function getURL()
{
    //echo $_GET['url'];
    if(isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        $url = rtrim($_GET['url'], '/');
        $url = filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
        $url = explode('/', $url);
        return $url;
    }
}}
```

- Proyecto
  -app
  -config
  -controladores
  -Paginas.php
  -helpers
  -librerias
  -Base.php
  -Controlador
  -Core
  -modelos
  -vistas
  -public
  -css
  -img

Si alguien me puede ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo.

Comment: Hola Carlos. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967) en el apartado **Otra posibilidad** explico una técnica que podría ser interesante para tu caso. Se trata simplemente de tener definidas en un solo lugar las rutas de tu proyecto y luego usar esas constantes en los cientos o miles o millones de archivos donde vayas a referirte a alguna de tus rutas. Así por ejemplo, si defines una ruta para `../app/controladores/` con una constante llamada `CONTROLS`, luego usarías `CONTROLS` en todo y si un día la ruta debiera cambiar, la cambias solamente en el archivo...

Comment: ... donde has definido dicha ruta asociándola a la constante `CONTROLS`. O sea, que si usas esa ruta en 5, en 500, en 5,000 o en 50,000 archivos. no vas a tener que ir a esos `N` archivos a cambiar rutas una por una, sino que la cambiarías únicamente en el archivo único donde la has definido. No sé si se entiende la enorme utilidad de hacer algo así. Otra recomendación que podría ser interesante para tu proyecto es el uso de [Autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.oop5.autoload.php), pero ese es ya otro asunto. Lo dejo caer simplemente para que lo tengas en cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

Observa tu variable `protected $controladorActual = 'paginas';` y notarás que hay una diferencia de nombres entre el valor de la misma y el nombre del archivo `**P**aginas`, para pasar la extension de tu archivo te recomiendo que declares este codigo al inicio de cada fichero o como una variable global accesibe para todas tus classes`$phpEx = substr(strrchr(__FILE__, '.'), 1);`y luego en tu include al fichero coloques esto  `require_once '../app/contoladores/'.ucwords($this->controladorActual).$phpEx;`
Saludos y espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Hola Javier! Muy buenas noches, sucede que para esa situación utilice el ucwords de hecho en el error sale que el archivo "Paginas.php" no existe esta en mayusculas y disculpa mi ignorancia soy un estudiante pero para que sirve la variable $phpEx

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$phpEx' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\app\librerias\Core.php on line 16

Comment: Ahora aparece ese error