# Redirección erronea

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me surgió un problema que por mas que busco en la red no acabo de encontrar, tengo una pagina con un form de contacto que funciona genial, se envia, y seguidamente redirige un pagina de agradecimiento conforme se ha enviado el correo y un boton abajo con un href que se supone que debe redirigir a inicio:

-->En dicho href no me redirige a la pagina principal porque solo me sobreescribe el nombre del archivo, pero la ruta del directorio no varia se me queda tal que así la url "www.eldominio.com/view/gracias.php", cuando quiero que ponga simplemente "eldominio.com"

[image: img_torna_inici]

utilizo MVC  y dejo el index en el mismo indice que las carpetas.

```
<div align="center">
<a href="index.php"><button class="w3-button  indieflower tipografia_texto_gris w3-section" type="submit">Torna a inici</button>
</a>
</div>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. ¿El archivo donde está el botón se encuentra en la carpeta raíz (donde está el `index.php`) o está en otra carpeta? ¿Revisaste posibles redirecciones en el `.htaccess`?

Comment: Yo lo tengo asi:   Carpeta(model) Carpeta(view) Carpeta(controller) y el INDEX.PHP

Comment: No entiendo. Pulsa en [edit]  y explica la estructura de carpetas donde está cada archivo. Puedes poner un pequeño árbol o mostrar una captura de pantalla donde se vea dónde está cada archivo implicado.

Comment: El archivo que me da las gracias esta dentro de la carpeta view.

Comment: vale formulkare mejor la pregunta dame 1 min

Comment: Pon una captura del árbol de carpetas, donde se vea la ubicación de cada archivo.

Comment: lo acabo de hacer, el index esta en la carpeta elrebostdelte

Comment: en la segunda imagen se ve claro, me gustaria que en vez que el archivo siguiera la ruta del directorio, que se eliminara la url y pusiera la web principal, es decir que redirija directamente a www.elrebostdelte.com

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110190/discussion-between-castronox-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Prueba a ponerlo así: `href="../index.php"`

Comment: me hace lo mismo, me sobre escribe en la url, en el navegador, la url me sale asi http://localhost/elrebostdelte/view/gracias.php   y cuando hago lo que sea por cambiarlo me lo deja asi http://localhost/elrebostdelte/view/www.elrebostdelte.com con un 404 en consecuencia.

Comment: cuando lo que querria es que lo borre todo, y ponga nada mas www.elrebostdelte.com

Comment: Si `gracias.php` está dentro de `view` y `view` está dentro de `elrebostdelte` y `index.php` está también dentro de `elrebostdelte`, poniéndolo así debería funcionar: `href="../index.php"` ahí cuando pones `../` le indicas que retroceda un directorio, o sea, que vaya a  `elrebostdelte` donde encontrará a `index.php`. Si no te funciona así entonces es debido a redirecciones en el `.htaccess`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en la imagen no veo claro que `index.php`  esté en el `elrebostdelte` ¿? Parece que no hay ningún archivo `index.php` en el directorio raíz: `elrebostdelte`

Comment: si que esta si, volvi a editar la pregunta amigo para que lo veas

Comment: Nooop. Ahí se ve claramente que `index.php` está dentro de `view`, no dentro de `elrebostdelte`. Por eso cuando lo pones con `../` te da error 404, porque no encuentra un archivo `index.php` en el directorio raíz.

Comment: la carpeta cuando tiene la flecha apuntando a la derecha la carpeta esta cerrada te hago un copy path para que veas

Comment: C:/xampp/htdocs/elrebostdelte/index.php

Comment: ¿Cuando en el `href` pones `../` qué URL  sale? ¿No sale acaso `C:/xampp/htdocs/elrebostdelte/index.php`?

Comment: amigo solucionado, era tu respuesta de todos modos pero al estar modificando contigo tanto en esta ultima se me olvido guardar cambios amigo ya lo tengo. tendras tu tic verde como respuesta oficial. copia y pegalo fuera del chat este y lo dejamos finalizxado si quieres

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si `gracias.php` está dentro de `view` y `view` está dentro de `elrebostdelte` y `index.php` está también dentro de `elrebostdelte`, poniéndolo así debería funcionar:

```
href="../index.php"
```

Cuando pones `../` en una ruta lo que indicas es **que retroceda un directorio**, o sea, que vaya a  `elrebostdelte` donde encontrará a `index.php`.

Si no te funciona así entonces es debido a redirecciones en el `.htaccess`.

De todos modos, te aconsejaría que manejes tus rutas usando constantes predefinidas. Así, si algún día tienes que cambiar algo lo haces en un solo sitio, sin tener que ir a todos los archivos a cambiar esas rutas. Para más detalles sobre esto, revisa el apartado **Otra posibilidad** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).