# Como debo cargar ficheros que están fuera de public_html?

Tags: php, javascript, html

como estan?

Estoy subiendo mi primer proyecto web a un hosting compartido. En dicha web hay un formulario que envía un mail por medio de PHPMailer, el cual tiene mis credenciales. Por temas de seguridad dejé tanto las validaciones en .js del form como los ficheros .php que se encargan de enviar el email con las credenciales fuera de la ruta public_html. El problema es que el sitio web no lee ningún fichero que esté fuera del directorio public_html y no sé como solucionar esto. Que debería hacer?

Muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Puedes definir rutas por medio de constantes en un archivo PHP, e incluir ese archivo donde vayas a usar esas rutas. Por ejemplo, digamos que tu archivo de rutas se llama `dirs.php` y lo tienes un `public_html`, incluyes ese archivo y luego llamas a cada ruta según la constante definida, eso te dará flexibilidad si en un futuro hay que cambiar cualquier ruta, porque estarían todas centralizadas en un solo sitio que es tu archivo `dirs.php` Para los archivos que están fuera de `public_html` deberás definir rutas absolutas como `home/carpeta/archivo.extension`

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano gracias por tu respuesta. Si bien creo que entiendo lo que dices, no me queda claro como debería acceder a mis archivos .php y .js. Mi formulario cuando hace submit accede a validaciones.js que lo revisa y comprueba que todos los campos sean validos. Una vez que eso sucede, envia los campos mediante fetch a enviar.php. Como quedaría configurado esto con la opcion que me recomiendas? Actualmente la comprobacion no se hace debido a que validaciones.js se encuentra fuera de public_html

Comment: Supongo que el archivo que tiene a `validaciones.js` es un archivo .php ¿no? En ese archivo donde incluyes a `validaciones.js` primero incluyes a tu archivo `dirs.php` y usas la ruta definida en dicho archivo para `validaciones.js`. Allí puedes implementar incluso la definición de rutas en cascada. Revisa el apartado titulado **Otra posibilidad** en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).

Comment: Ahi leí la documentacion que me dejaste anexada y me queda un poco más claro. Aún así el script validaciones.js se invoca desde el html, por lo tanto se solicita ni bien se ejecuta la carga de la misma

Comment: Ya, pero lo que preguntaba es sobre la extensión del archivo, ¿es extensión `.html` o es extensión `.php`?

Comment: La web es html. www.lascameliasfloreria.com.ar en este momento está cargada pero no está funcionando el formulario. El código intenta cargar validaciones.js, y como no lo carga el envio de datos por fetch no se ejecuta. Además al hacer submit intenta enviar la información a .php, y tampoco se encuentra la ruta

Comment: No, generalmente el punto de entrada de las web es el archivo `index.php` que se encuentra en la carpeta `public_html`, ese archivo no es extensión `.html`, **sino que es extensión `.php`**. Repito de nuevo, me refiero a la **extensión** del archivo, no a su contenido. **Lo que quieres hacer tiene que partir sí o sí de un archivo con extensión `.php`**, porque desde un archivo con extensión `.html` sería complicado hacerlo, salvo pasando por procedimientos oscuros que abrirían agujeros de seguridad en tu web.

Comment: 1. Por temas de seguridad las validaciones deben hacerse siempre del lado del servidor (sólo detalles mínimos como no nulidad de campos y formatos elementales, se dejan para el cliente) 2. El código a cargo de procesos va fuera del directorio público, pero el código js y css que se ocupa de dinámica y presentación de las página puede estar en carpetas dentro de aquel (ya que en general va a ser servido junto con las páginas). Debes reorganizar un poco