# No se visualiza pagina migrada de un dominio a otro

Tags: php, html, url

Hola buenas tardes migre una página de un dominio a otro cambiando los DNS correctamente pero el contenido de la página no se está visualizando, la verdad no entiendo muy bien la estructura del sitio ya que no se utilizó un framwork para su desarrollo, pero les comento lo que e investigado.
Esta es la url del sitio donde la pagina si se visualiza https://ucx.mx/ y quiere pasar la página también a este dominio https://ucx.edu.mx/ . La pagina ya esta en el CPanel en public_html pero no se vizualiza su contenido, entonces comente la siguiente línea de código include("includes/head.php") ubicado en el index.php y la pagina empieza a tomar forma pero no carga los estilos, entonces note que utilizan mucho ABS_HTTP_URL no se si se refiera a la base_url que normalmente utilizo en CodeIgniter, intente busca en todo el proyecto donde se declare ABS_HTTP_URL pero no encuentro nada es por eso que acudo a ustedes.
Les comparto el código del index.php y algunas capturas de pantalla.

> Dominio original https://ucx.mx/

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Dominio donde se quiere pasar la pagina https://ucx.edu.mx/ sin
> comentar include("includes/head.php"); en el index.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con include("includes/head.php"); comentado en el archivo index.php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código index.php

```
<?php 
    $title_header = 'Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa | Licenciatura en Odontología. Diplomados en Endodoncia.';
    $meta = "Universidad Cuauhtémoc Campus Xalapa. Primera escuela privada de odontología en Xalapa. Licenciatura de Odontología. Diplomado en Endodoncia.";
    include("includes/head.php"); 
?>
<!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?>assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?>assets/owl-carousel/owl.full.css">
<?php include("includes/header.php");?>
<!--Microdatos-->
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" style="display:none">
  <span itemprop="description">Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa | Licenciatura en Odontología. Diplomados en Endodoncia.</span>
  <span itemprop="image"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?>images/template/ucx.png</span>
  <span itemprop="name">Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa</span>
  <span itemprop="url"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?></span>
<div itemprop="author" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Corporation" >
  <span itemprop="description">Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa - Primera escuela privada de odontología en Xalapa</span>
  <span itemprop="image"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?>images/template/ucx.png</span>
  <span itemprop="name">Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa</span>
  <span itemprop="url"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?></span>
<div itemprop="contactPoint" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ContactPoint">
  <span itemprop="telephone"> (52) 228 817 3434</span>
  <span itemprop="telephone"> (52) 228 817 6727</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="Brand" itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/Brand">
  <span itemprop="name">Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa</span>
  <span itemprop="url"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?></span>
  <span itemprop="logo"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?>images/template/ucx.png</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="location" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place" >
  <span itemprop="description">Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa - Primera escuela privada de odontología en Xalapa</span>
  <span itemprop="image"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?>images/template/ucx.png</span>
  <span itemprop="name">Universidad Cuauhtémoc. Campus Xalapa</span>
  <span itemprop="url"><?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?></span>
<div itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">
  <span itemprop="streetAddress">Av. M. Ávila Camacho N° 129 Edificio GYRO, Frente al Teatro del Estado </span>
  <span itemprop="addressLocality">Xalapa Enríquez</span>
  <span itemprop="addressRegion">Veracruz</span>
  <span itemprop="postalCode">91000</span>
</div>
<div itemprop="geo" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/GeoCoordinates">
  <meta itemprop="latitude" content="19.533148" />
  <meta itemprop="longitude" content="-96.933355" />
</div>
</div> <!--Place-->
</div><!--Corporation-->
</div><!--Web Page-->
<!--Microdatos-->
<div id="content">
    <article>
        <section id="anchor-inicio"></section>
        <!-- Slider -->
        <div class="re-owl-slider">
            <div id="owl-full" class="owl-carousel">
                <div class="item"> 
                    <img  src="<?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL ?>images-slider/Correcion.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
```

Nota: solo coloque una fracción de código

Archivo head.php

```
<?php include_once 'system/common.php';?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title><?php echo $title_header; ?></title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="description" content="<?php echo $meta;?>">
        <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW" /> 
        <meta name="robots" content="NOODP,NOYDIR" />
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
        <meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:200,300,400,600,700,900,300italic,400italic,600italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <base href="<?=ABS_HTTP_URL;?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/theme.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/color-defaults.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/swatch-white-azul.css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/fonts.min.css" media="screen">
        
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[class*=botonWhats]');
                for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
                    var button = buttons[i];
                    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
                        console.log('funciona');
                        gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                            'send_to': 'AW-702401622/fbV6CJapkdQBENaY984C'
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        </script>
        
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: 702401622 -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-702401622"></script>
        <script>
          window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
          function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
          gtag('js', new Date());
        
          gtag('config', 'AW-702401622');
        </script>
```

> Archivo common.php

```
<?php
@session_start();
error_reporting(0);
define('IPVALID', ProjectLibrary_FrontEnd_Util_Session::Get('debug'));
if(IPVALID)error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

define("DEVELOPMENT_TEST", false && IPVALID);
if( defined('DEVELOPMENT_TEST') && DEVELOPMENT_TEST){
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
}

/**
 * This function loads ALL classes required by the application
 *
 * @param string $class_name
 * @return void
 */
function __autoload( $class_name ){

    $debug = defined('DEVELOPMENT_TEST') ? DEVELOPMENT_TEST : false;
    $path = array ( );
    
    $pathToLib = 'libs/';
    
    if ( strpos( $class_name, 'Zend_') === 0 ){
        $path[] = $pathToLib . str_replace( "_", "/", $class_name ) . ".php";
    }
    else {
        $path[] = $pathToLib . str_replace( "_", "/", $class_name ) . ".class.php";
        $path[] = $pathToLib . "CoreLibrary/" . str_replace( "_", "/", $class_name ) . ".class.php";
        $path[] = $pathToLib . "CoreLibrary/Exceptions/" . str_replace( "_", "/", $class_name ) . ".class.php";
        $path[] = $pathToLib . "PEAR/" . str_replace( "_", "/", $class_name ) . ".php";
        $path[] = $pathToLib . "PhpMailer/class." . $class_name . ".php";
        $path[] = $pathToLib . "PayPal/" . str_replace( "_", "/", $class_name ) . ".php";
    }
    
    if ( $debug ){
        echo "Looking for <b>$class_name</b><br>";
    }
    
    $found = false;
    
    $include_paths = explode( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path() );
    
    foreach ( $path as $filename ){
        if ( $debug ){
            echo "Filename: " . $filename . ' ... ';
        }
        if(defined('DEVELOPMENT_TEST') && DEVELOPMENT_TEST){
            if ( include_once ( $filename ) ){
                if ( $debug ){
                    echo "<B>FOUND</B><br>";
                }
                return;
            } else{
                if ( $debug ){
                    echo "Not found <br>";
                }
            }
        }else{
            if ( @include_once ( $filename ) ){
                if ( $debug ){
                    echo "<B>FOUND</B><br>";
                }
                return;
            } else{
                if ( $debug ){
                    echo "Not found <br>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ( $debug ){
        echo "<br>";
    }
    if ( $found ){
        return true;
    }
    
    // The following line is required so no Fatal error is returned and the exception is launched
    eval( 'class ' . $class_name . ' extends ClassNotFoundException {}' );
    
    // Prepare the exception descriptive text.
    $txt = "The class <b>$class_name</b> could not be found under the following paths:<br>";
    $txt .= '<ul><li>' . join( '</li><li>', $path ) . '</li></ul>';
    
    throw new ClassNotFoundException( $txt );
}

/**
 * Debug function that writes to the output buffer the var_dump() information
 * from the given $var using $msg as label. The var_dump information is 
 * <pre>formatted.
 *
 * @param mixed $var The variable to debug
 * @param string $msg The label to prepend before the debug information
 */
function debug( $var, $msg = null ){
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $msg;
    ob_start();
    var_dump( $var );
    $debug = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    
    $debug = htmlentities( $debug );
    
    echo str_replace( "=>\n", "=>", $debug );
    
    echo '</pre>';
}

@session_start();

setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'es_MX');

define( 'ABS_PATH', dirname( __FILE__ ) );
define( 'SYSTEM_DIRECTORY', 'system/');
define( 'BO_DIRECTORY', 'system/');

// Initialize default constants
Config::Initialize();

// Initialize the error handler
ExceptionHandler::initialize();

//define ("CHARSET_PROJECT", empty($CHARSET) ? "ISO-8859-1" : $CHARSET);
define ("CHARSET_PROJECT", empty($CHARSET) ? "UTF-8" : $CHARSET);
define ("CHARSET_PROJECT_DB", "utf8");

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . CHARSET_PROJECT);

if( defined('LANGUAGE') ){
    $lang = ProjectLibrary_SDO_Core_Application_LanguageManager::GetActualLanguage();
    if(LANGUAGE != $lang){
            ProjectLibrary_SDO_Core_Application_LanguageManager::SetActualLanguage( LANGUAGE );
    }
}

?>
```

Espero que me puedan orientar.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola Javier, ya tienes suficiente puntuación como para redactar bien una pregunta. Los enlaces están mal, pulsa en [edit] para corregirlo. Ya que has migrado la URL como dices, indica qué reglas `.htaccess` tienes escritas para redirigir del viejo al nuevo dominio.

Comment: ya agregue un .htacces y ni aun asi carga la pagina, mi sospecha es donde esta ese ABS_HTTP_URL que apunta al dominio.

Comment: `ABS_HTTP_URL` es una constante que debería estar definida en alguna parte. Puedes hacer un `var_dump(ABS_HTTP_URL);` en cualquier parte y ver lo que imprime. Puede que eso haya sido heredado de Wordpress u otro CMS o framework. Si ahora el sitio funciona sin CMS ni framework, igualmente puedes definir tus constantes e incluirlas.

Comment: me manda el siguiente error cuando lo imprimo. Warning: Use of undefined constant ABS_HTTP_URL - assumed 'ABS_HTTP_URL' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PaginaWebAC\index.php on line 3
string(12) "ABS_HTTP_URL"

Comment: Correcto, justo lo que te decía antes, `ABS_HTTP_URL` es una constante que estaba definida por algún CMS o framework del sitio anterior. Por el nombre podría ser la ruta absoluta de tu dominio (la del directorio root). Puedes probar a definirla con algo como esto: `define("ABS_HTTP_URL", "Aqui-la-ruta-a-la-que-se-quiere-hacer-referencia-con-la-constante");`

Comment: seria asi? define("ABS_HTTP_URL", "ucx.edu.mx");

Comment: Sería mejor la ruta completa, incluyendo `http` o `https`, según el caso. O, usar `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`. De todos modos tienes que probar si realmente en el contexto esa constante se refiere a eso, cuando la definas puedes comprobar que la combinación de esa constante con el resto de la cadena estaría apuntando a la ruta correcta donde se encuentran los archivos.

Comment: Por ejemplo aquí: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo ABS_HTTP_URL;?>assets/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css">` lo que representaría `ABS_HTTP_URL` debería ser el root y se sigue completando una ruta ... la carpeta `assets`  que estaría en el root y dentro de `assets` una sub-carpeta `owl-carousel` donde estaría el archivo css. Tienes que verificar eso en la estructura de tus carpetas/archivos.

Comment: lo que hice fue correrlo primero en local, ya coloque define("ABS_HTTP_URL", "http://PaginaWebAC");   -------------- PaginaWebAC es el nombre de mi proyecto

Comment: No sé que representaría ahí `PaginaWebAC` si es una constante y defines a `ABS_HTTP_URL` como otra constante ¿?

Comment: tengo en htdocs una carpeta llamada PaginaWebAC  y dentro de la carpeta tengo la pagina web y por eso fue que lo definí así define("ABS_HTTP_URL", "PaginaWebAC") y dentro de la carpeta PaginaWebAC esta assets etc etc..

Comment: pero no carga los estilos ni nada

Comment: ¿En qué ruta **absoluta** está tu carpeta `assets`? ¿Dentro de ella está la carpeta `owl-carousel` y dentro de ella archivos como `owl.carousel.css`? La cuestión es simple: 1º. Definir correctamente tus constantes; 2º Verificar que los archivos/carpetas fueron migrados al lugar correcto.

Comment: es correcto, así es como esta la estructura pero esta muy raro porque no carga los estilos

Comment: Agrega a la pregunta una captura de tu estructura de archivos, abierta desde el root, en `assets` y sus sub-carpetas. Me refiero al nuevo dominio, no al viejo.

Comment: ya quedo, no había guardado cambios haaaaaaaa, me timó el editor de texto.

Comment: Revisa el apartado ***Otra posibilidad*** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967), quizá te puede servir para crear adecuadamente tus propias constantes y rutas de archivo.