# Error en include () PHP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, php7

Esta es mi primera vez trabajando con php y quiero incluir el archivo topics.php dentro los archivos index.php, create.php y edit.php dentro la carpeta topics dentro la carpeta admin como se ve en mi directorio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARgQT.jpg
Lo estoy haciendo de la siguiente manera

```
<?php 
include('../../path.php');

include(ROOT_PATH . '/app/controllers/topics.php')
 ?>
```

En donde el archivo path.php contiene el siguiente código

```
<?php
define("ROOT_PATH", realpath(dirname('_FILE_'))); 
define('BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/blog'); 
?>
```

Al refrescar obtengo el siguiente error

```
Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics/app/controllers/topics.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\create.php on line 4


Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics/app/controllers/topics.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\create.php on line 4
```

Ahora, si decido no usar el `ROOT_PATH` y hago el include de la siguiente forma:

```
include( '../../app/controllers/topics.php')
```

Me da los siguientes errores

```
Warning: include(C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics/app/database/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\controllers\topics.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics/app/database/db.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\controllers\topics.php on line 3

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function selectAll() in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\controllers\topics.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics\edit.php(7): include() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\app\controllers\topics.php on line 12
```

Agradezco mucho su ayuda

Comment: Haz un `echo ROOT_PATH;` y dinos qué muestra. Y, usa la herramienta de Stackoverflow para incluir la captura de tu estructura de archivos.

Comment: Al hacer `echo ROO_PATH`  muestra esto `C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics
` 
Y graicas por la sugerencia, es la primera vez que uso esta plataforma.

Comment: Según la imagen, el archivo `topics.php` se encuentra en la ruta: `blog/app/controllers`, no en `blog\admin\topics`. Te recomiendo que definas constantes en cascada por cada directorio y sub-directorio, así evitarás confusiones como estas. Si tuvieras definida una constante **en cascada** para `controllers`, harías el include simplemente usando esa constante, así sabrías a qué directorio referirte sin riesgo de confusión. Revisa el apartado **Otra posibilidad** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967) donde se explica como definir los directorios en cascada.

Comment: Debes tener cuidado al definir las constantes y las partes de nombres de archivo, cuidar que si las rutas terminan por `/`, que no empieces los nombres de archivos por `/` para no tener un doble `//`. Luego, para depurar, es fácil ver la ruta que se creará al hacer esto: `include(ROOT_PATH . '/app/controllers/topics.php')`, concatenamos lo definido en `ROOT_PATH` y el resto, y obtendrás esto: **`C:\xampp\htdocs\blog\admin\topics/app/controllers/topics.php`** esa desde luego no es la ruta correcta, no lo es por la ruta en sí y no sé si en Windows es válido el slash invertido para PHP ¿?