# ¿Como puedo redirigir a un archivo PHP desde cualquier nivel de una carpeta?

Tags: php

Tengo el siguiente mapa de sitio

- Root

  **index.php**

  - carpeta1

    - carpeta1.1

      **ejemplo1.php**

      - Carpeta1.1.1

        **ejemplo2.php**

El problema es que deseo redirigir al archivo `index.php` desde cualquier lugar, de lo contrario tendría que utilizar la subida de nivel `../` y lo que quiero es un tipo de logout que siempre me lleve al inicio sin saber el nivel en el que estoy.

Actualmente tengo este código en una función de `POO` de `php`y no me funciona en ciertos archivos.

```
header("Location:../../index.php");
```

Comment: Si fuera tú, definiría constantes en cascada para cada ruta y usaría esas constantes al momento de redirigir. Así, si por algún motivo alguna ruta debe cambiar en un futuro sólo la cambias en el archivo donde defines las constantes. Se agradece, sobre todo en proyectos grandes, donde tendrías que buscar a mano cientos o miles de archivos donde pusiste rutas *hard coded* para hacer el cambio. Si te interesa hacerlo así, consulta el apartado **Otra posibilidad** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).

Comment: Lo estaba revisando, en el directorio tendría que poner la carpeta raíz que envuelva a otras subcarpetas, es decir; tengo una carpeta llamada php la cual tiene cinco subcarpetas y estas a su vez otras, la dirección tendría que ser la de la carpeta php y de ahi ir subiendo?

Answer (score 1):

La redirección se hace por URL, no por la estructura de tu directorio.

```
header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/index.php');
```

- recordá que un `header()` tiene que enviarse antes que cualquier otro texto en el PHP

Comment: Es mu tonta la pregunta, funciona igual en `XAMPP` mientras hago pruebas?

Comment: Si, para eso es efectivamente XAMPP, bueno, al menos a mi me funciona

Comment: @FernyCortez no hay preguntas tontas. Por otro lado, XAMPP no tiene nada que ver con esto. XAMPP es el instlador/gestor/llamalo como quieras que te instaló PHP en tu máquina. Esto es PHP y código de PHP