# ¿Cuál es la ruta?

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Estoy aprendiendo como hacer las rutas para poder manipular archivos independiente de su lugar.

¿Cuál es la ruta para poder cargar el código de los archivos en PHP?

```
<?php 
include("???");
```

Comment: Imposible responderte si no nos compartes la estructura de carpeta de tu proyecto y señales donde esta el archivo que deseas incluir y dond el archivo donde lo incluiremos, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: Bien, ahora  ¿cuál es el problema en si con ese código?

Comment: El archivo que debes mostrarnos sería index por que en ese (*según la URL*) es donde ocurre el fallo, además los mensajes de error deben ir como texto

Comment: En [¿Cómo manejar rutas de archivos en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/221201) tienes una buena explicación de las rutas en PHP. Si no responde a tu problema, puede ayudarte a exponerlo mejor.