# Warning: require_once(./core/confiAPP.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta a la base de datos de mysql, la confiuguracion de la conexion la tengo en un archivo aparte, este es el codigo del archivo de conexion

```
    <?php

 class Conexion {
      static public function conectar(){
          $link = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mvcproyecto', "root", "");  
          $link->exec("set name utf8");

          return $link;
         }
 }
```

este es el codigo en el modelo con nombre actividadModelo.php

```
    <?php
require_once "./core/confiAPP.php";

class actividadModelo{

    protected $id;
    protected $nombre;
    protected $clasificacion;
    protected $foto;
    protected $foto_url;
    protected $video_url;
    protected $contenido;

    protected function InserActividad(){
        $stmtuno = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO actividades(nombre, clasificacion, foto, foto_url, video_url, contenido) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmtuno->bindParam(1,$this->nombre);
        $stmtuno->bindParam(2,$this->clasificacion);
        $stmtuno->bindParam(2,$this->clasificacion);
        $stmtuno->bindParam(3,$this->foto);
        $stmtuno->bindParam(4,$this->foto_url);
        $stmtuno->bindParam(5,$this->video_url);
        $stmtuno->bindParam(6,$this->contenido);
        $stmtuno->execute();
    }

    public function SearchAllActividad(){
        echo ('a'); die;
        $stmtdos = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM actividades");
        var_dump($stmtdos);
        $stmtdos->execute();
        $a  = $stmtdos->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        return $a;
    }
 }
```

al ejecutarlo me da los siguientes errores

> Warning: require_once(./core/confiAPP.php): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\softwareEdu\modelos\actividadModelo.php on line 2
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required
> './core/confiAPP.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\softwareEdu\modelos\actividadModelo.php on line 2

el detalle es que es solo al momento de consultar, por que para realizar el insert de los datos funciona correctamente, estoy trabajando con php MVC sin ningun tipo de framework.

estructura de carpetas del proyecto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes problema con la ubicación del archivo, ¿estás seguro que la ruta es la correcta?

Comment: Agrega el nombre de cada archivo y el código completo para saber cual es la linea 2 y a que archivo corresponde.

Comment: el archivo de conexion esta en la ruta /core/confiApp.php

Comment: el modelo es el segundo bloque de codigo y se llama y se llama actividadModelo.php

Comment: BetaM, si ese es la ruta, al momento de guardar utiliza esa misma ruta y fuciona correctamente, es al consulta que me da esos errores

Comment: Core en que jerarquía está en cuestión de modelos?

Comment: Definitivo algo esta mal en la ruta que usas, edita y agrega la estructura de tu árbol de carpetas así como la sentencia *require* que da problemas y en que archivo esta esta misma

Comment: Dentro de `/core` está confiAPP.php? El nombre del archivo es exactamente ese, con mayúsculas y tal? Si es así, tiene permisos suficientes para que Apache lo use?

Comment: proba con [`__DIR__ . "/../core/confiAPP.php"`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.magic.php) o de última con [`realpath( __DIR__ . "/../core/" ) . "confiAPP.php"`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php)

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/softwareEdu/core/confiAPP.php");
```

Puedes ver más detalles aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/225338