# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Tags: php

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy intentando hacer un require_once de un archivo en php, pero estoy teniendo problemas, tengo una variable llamada `$filename` que es el nombre del archivo al que quiero incluir, y una constante llamada `ROOT_DIRECTORY` la cual es el directorio de mi archivo, el problema es con este codigo:

```
require_once ROOT_DIRECTORY . "views/" . $filename;
```

Y obtengo este error:

> Warning: require_once(directorio ):
> Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
> nombre_del_archivo on line 55

Pero en cambio si acceso al archivo al que quiero hacer el require si es que existe, alguien me puede ayudar diciendome por que php no reconoce el archivo y como lo puedo arreglar? Desde ya gracias.

### Edit

Este edit lo hice para agregar mas informacion:

- Servidor web: apache
- La constante ROOT_DIRECTORY es la ruta absoluta al archivo
- Estoy en linux
- El archivo al que quiero acceder se encuentra donde debe de estar y
  esta accesible
- Si hago `echo ROOT_DIRECTORY . "views/" . $filename` el resultado es la ruta al
  archivo exacto al que quiero acceder

Y por ultimo quiero agregar que si elimino la variable `$filename` y dejo la linea asi `echo ROOT_DIRECTORY . "views/archivo.php"` ya no da error, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Comment: ¿Si haces un `echo ROOT_DIRECTORY . "views/" . $filename` que obtienes?  Si luego vas a un terminal y intentas hacer un `stat` de esa ruta que has obtenido con el archivo te sale algo?  (digo `stat` por decir algo, con `ls -lat` tambien te funcionaria).  ¿En que entorno estas? Windows? Linux? Que servidor web? Apache?  Que versión de PHP?  Deberias tambien especificar todas esas cosas al preguntar por si acaso son de ayuda (en este caso no todas, pero por costumbre digo). ¿La ruta es relativa o absoluta?

Comment: @masterguru listo, agrege la informacion que me dijiste. Saludos

Comment: Pues el problema pinta en el valor de la variable `$filename`, pero dices que lo has recomprobado bien, así que ni idea, no tiene sentido.  Quizas podrias depurarlo un poco más haciendo un `is_file()` de esa ruta antes de hacer el `require_once` para ver si tampoco lo ve asi y si por si muestra más información de error que te pueda ayudar.

Comment: A menos que sea un problema de sintaxis, que tenga que ir encerrado entre parentesis o comillas todo ello

Comment: @masterguru listo, ya agrege el problema y la solucion. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al parecer el problema estaba en esta linea `ROOT_DIRECTORY . "views/" . $filename` ya que al hacer eso al final del texto se agregaba un espacio, y php no encontraba el archivo por el espacio agregado, solo tuve que cambiar eso por esto `trim(ROOT_DIRECTORY . "views/" . $filename)` y ya no hubo problemas. Aunque no se porque se agrega un espacio en blanco

Comment: Dudo que le agregara un espacio en blanco, pues lo terminabas con `$filename;`.  Eso es que el `$filename` ya lo debia contener seguramente, o bien eso de la sintaxis que te decia antes, de encerrarlo entre paréntesis.

Comment: @masterguru yo creí lo mismo, pero si hacia un `var_dump` del texto me lo devolvía con un espacoi al final

Comment: Usar `trim` aquí no es la solución más óptima. Deberías revisar dónde se está produciendo ese espacio en blanco y eliminarlo, hasta entonces tu programa no estará optimizado. Es así como se crean programas deficientes donde luego hay que estar parcheando cosas a medio camino cuando debieron resolverse en el origen. Por otro lado, yo definiría constantes escalonadas para las rutas, o sea, una constante también para `views`, a partir del root y luego usar esa constante. [Revisa esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967) en el apartado **Otra posibilidad**.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias, voy a hacer los cambios que están en el link que me pasaste e intentaré eliminar el espacio en blanco de otra forma. Saludos