# ¿Por que me da un error de clase no encontrada en php, cuando la he utilizado en otras occasions como por ejemplo llenar un combo con php?

Tags: php, html

Buenas noches a todos.

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente. Estoy desarrollando un pequeño sistema y me pasa lo siguiente. Aclaro que soy nuevo en este tema y se me ardieron los libros.

Cuando intento que haga una consulta me arroja el siguiente erro.

Mi estructura de orden la tengo de la siguiente manera.

[![Orden de mi proyecto][1]][1]

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'claseConexion' not found in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myProyect\Recursos\recursos.php:30 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myProyect\Clases\MetodosPropios\AltaUsuario.php(3):
> include() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myProyect\Recursos\recursos.php on line 30

Tengo la clase ClaseConexion.

```
class claseConexion{
    
    private $varConexion;
    public $varError;

    public function __construct($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $basedatos){
        if(!$this->_connect($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $basedatos)){
            $this->varError = $this->varConexion->connect_error;
        }
        
    }

    function __destruct()
    {
        $this->varConexion->close();
    }

    private function _connect($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $basedatos){
        $this->varConexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $contraseña, $basedatos);
        if(!$this->varConexion->connect_errno){
            $this->varError = $this->varConexion->connect_error;
            return false;
        }    
    }

 public function  ejecutaQuery($cSQL){

        $sentencia = strtoupper(substr($cSQL, 0, 6));

        switch ($sentencia){
            case 'INSERT':
                $sql = $this->varConexion->query($cSQL);
                    if(!$sql){
                        $this->varError = $this->varConexion->varError;
                        return false;
                    }
                break;
            case 'UPDATE':
                $sql = $this->varConexion->query($cSQL);
                    if(!$sql){
                        $this->varError = $this->varConexion->varError;
                    }
                break;
            case 'DELETE':
                $sql = $this->varConexion->query($cSQL);
                    if(!$sql){
                        $this->varError = $this->varConexion->VarError;
                    }
                break;
            case 'SELECT':
                $sql = $this->varConexion->query($cSQL);
                if(!$sql){
                    $this->varError = $this->varConexion->varError;
                }else{
                    while($next = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
                        $listaRegistros[] = $next;
                    }
                    return $listaRegistros;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Además tengo dos clases, una llamada consulta

```
Class Consultas{
    private $conexion;

    function __construct($con)
    {
        $this->conexion = $con;
    }

    public function listaEmpresa(){
        $query = $this->conexion->ejecutaQuery('SELECT * FROM ORDBDEMP');
        return $query;
    }
    
    public function listaPadron() {
        $query = $this->conexion->ejecutaQuery("SELECT * FROM ORDBPD");
        return $query;
    }
    
    public function selectPadron($args){
        $query = $this->conexion->ejecutaQuery("SELECT * FROM ORDBPD WHERE IDORDBPD = $args");
        return $query;
    }        
}
```

Clase Regisros

```
<?php
Class Registros{
    private $conexion;

    function __construct($con)
    {
        $this->conexion = $con;
    }

    public function RegistroUsuarios($ordbbdus,$ordbdusps,$ordbdidpd, $ordbdpdndoc){
        $query = $this->conexion->ejecutaQuery("INSERT INTO ordbdus (ORDBUSID,ORDBDUS,ORDBDUSPS,ORDBPD_IDORDBPD,ORDBPD_ORDBPDNRODOC)VALUES(DEFAULT,$ordbbdus,$ordbdusps,$ordbdidpd,$ordbdpdndoc)");
        return $query;
    }
}
```

Y otra llamada registros. Ambas están en una carpeta llamada Métodos, que a su vez está dentro de Clases. Ej.: /myProyect/Clases/Metodos y dentro de esta están los archivos Consultas.php y Registros.php.

En el constructor, traigo la conexión y los métodos para que ejecute cada consulta.

Por otro lado, tengo un archivo **recursos.php**, por supuesto dentro de una carpeta también llamada Recursos.
Ej.: "myProyect/Recursos/recursos.php"

Esta vendría a ser como un organizador de todo lo que haga o estoy haciendo hasta ahora.

```
<?php


include ('../Clases/Conexion.php');
include ('../Clases/Metodos/Registros.php');
include ('../Clases/Metodos/Consultas.php');

define('SERVIDOR', 'localhost:3306');
define('USUARIO', 'root');
define('CONTRASEÑA','xxxxxx');
define('BASEDATOS','orddb');

$cnx = new claseConexion(SERVIDOR,USUARIO,CONTRASEÑA,BASEDATOS)
  $registros = new Registros($cnx);
   $consultas = new Consultas($cnx);
```

Por último cuando quiero usar la clase consulta que incluyo a recursos.php en el
archivo AltaUsuario.php me salta el error presentado más arriba. -

```
<?php

include ('../../Recursos/recursos.php');

session_start();

$ordbdidpd = substr($_POST['nomUsuario'],0,1);
$ordbdus = $_POST['usuario'];
$ordbdusps = password_hash($_POST['contraseña'],PASSWORD_DEFAULT,array('const'=>4));
$ordcaptcha = $_POST['captcha'];

if($_SESSION['codigoCaptcha']==$ordcaptcha){
   $ordbnrodoc = $consultas->selectPadron($ordbdidpd);
   echo $ordbnrodoc[0]['ORDBPDNRODOC'];
  
}else{
    echo "Hay errores";
}
```

Sin más saludos a la comunidad y ante todo muchas gracias por su tiempo

Comment: Yo creo que primero deberías definir al constructor de claseConexion como público porque al no declararlo creo lo toma como private, y en vez de usar include te recomiendo require_once.

Comment: Lectura altamente recomendada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos. Reformulare la pregunta. Lo iba a hacer con código en forma de texto pero me daba errores de sangría.

Comment: ¿Que tal incluir la ruta completa en include('rutacompleta/recursos/recursos.php')? Me refiero a la ultima imagen.

Comment: [Revisa el apartado **Otra posibilidad** de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967). Te recomendaría que definas tus rutas en constantes, partiendo, en forma de árbol, desde tu directorio raíz, y usando en todos los casos las constantes de rutas. Una vez hecho eso, si el problema sigue, haz un `echo` de la constante de tu ruta y verifica que realmente es la correcta.

Comment: Gracias A. Cedano. pero hice tal cual explicaste en el link de acceso. pero nada agregue en el directorio raíz dirs.php con la que considere que debía ir y me dice que ahora no lo encuentra.

Comment: Estimado A. Cedano. De corazón te agradezco por esta ayuda, logre hacer que funcione y a su vez incorporé tú conocimiento para hacerlo mío. Gracias por ayudar a este principiante.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal como ya debes suponer, el problema viene dado por la anidación de varios archivos con funciones **include() con rutas relativas de distinto origen**, pues se toma como referencia relativa de su ruta el archivo invocado inicialmente, y no el resto de archivos que tambien tienen nuevos includes llamando a más archivos desde otras rutas.

Además de la solución comentada por A.Cedano, la cual **bien aplicada debería funcionarte**, puedes optar por esta otra solución, usando [realpath()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.realpath.php), [dirname()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.dirname.php) y la constante mágica [`__FILE__`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.constants.predefined.php):

```php
include (realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../Clases/Conexion.php');
```

donde:

- **realpath(dirname(**FILE**))** nos va a devolver la ruta completa del archivo actual pues tal como reza la definición de `__FILE__`:

> Ruta completa y nombre del fichero con enlaces simbólicos resueltos.
> Si se usa dentro de un include, devolverá el nombre del fichero
> incluido.

Y con eso conseguimos establecer inequívocamente el lugar donde se encuentra el archivo incluido con **include() de forma anidada** en otro archivo, sin que ello merme su localización real y pueda ser incluido correctamente a pesar de usar rutas relativas en includes anidados.

Comment: Hola masterguru. Gracias por tú ayuda, que junto con la de A.Cedano me han enseñado mucho, de corazón, Que tengan buena vida ambos.