# ¿Cómo puedo utlizar un include en otra página aunque las rutas cambien?

Tags: php

Tengo un problema con un `include  require_once` el cual contiene una barra lateral que tiene varios botones  en la  página principal funciona bien el botón cerrar sesión, pero el problema es que  al reutilizar el `include` con la barra lateral en otra carpeta  que es para crear otra página de crear publicaciones  ya no me funciona el botón cerrar sesión ya que la ruta cambia y si cambio la ruta del `include` ya no funcionaria en la página principal, la pregunta es:

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el botón funciona en las dos páginas y así solucionar ese error?[image: esa es la ruta del botón en la pagina principal pero si la cambio se daña, la pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que el botón funciona en las dos páginas?]

Comment: por definicion el login y el logout se dejan en la raiz para evitar esos inconvenientes
por ejemplo `<a href="/logout.php">salir</a>`

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: La mejor práctica sería tener tus rutas definidas en un sólo archivo y usar en todos los casos las constantes que definen cada ruta. Piensa en un proyecto más o menos grande, donde alguna ruta por ejemplo cambia a lo largo del tiempo y tienes esa ruta en cientos o miles de archivos. Teniendo la ruta centralizada, definida en un archivo, sólo la cambiarías ahí, no en los cientos o miles de archivos. Y es que sólo adivinar dónde estarías usando esa ruta sería un verdadero dolor de cabeza. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967) para más detalles.