# ¿las rutas no funcionan en php?

Tags: php, html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Problema con las rutas en php: **no funciona al reiniciar el pc con la misma ruta**.

Tengo el siguiente código que abre una imagen desde php:

```
<img src="../../institucion/acciones/sr.png" alt="imagen de prueba">
```

y funciona, pero la cuestion es que cuando apago o reinicio mi pc, ya esa ruta no me funciona sino que tengo que modificar así:

```
<img src="../institucion/acciones/sr.png" alt="imagen de prueba">
```

Así mismo pasa con los formularios.

¿Alguna sugerencia acerca de lo que debo hacer para solucionar este problema?

Comment: ¿En qué carpeta se encuentra `institucion` y en qué carpeta se encuentra el archivo donde tienes el código que nos muestras en la pregunta?

Comment: institucion es una carpeta que no esta guardada en ninguno directorio  del proyecto, o sea esta en la primera capa, y el codigo si lo tengo guardado en el directorio admin/contenidos/index.php. la cuestion es que el primer codigo funciona, pero cuando reinicio mi pc, ya me toca cambiar la ruta.

Comment: No entiendo tu comentario. En tus rutas tienes esto: `institucion/acciones/`, entonces, dinos dónde se encuentra `institucion` con respecto al archivo donde está el código que nos muestras. Si no sabes verbalizarlo, entonces haz una captura de pantalla donde se vean tus rutas y la agregas a la pregunta pulsando en [edit].

Comment: listo ya pegue la imagen, desde blog abro la imagen que esta en institucion/acciones/sr.png

Comment: Si `blog` e `institucion` están en la carpeta **`admin`**, esta es la forma correcta: `../institucion/acciones/sr.png`, pues `../` retrocedería un directorio, yendo a `admin`. De todos modos, no conviene que pongas tus rutas en cada elemento, sino que definas tus rutas en cascada usando constantes y uses esas constantes donde quieras. Revisa el apartado **otra posibilidad** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).