# problema para incluir base de dato en php

Tags: php, mysql

estoy empezando a utilizar bases de datos en php pero me sale un error al incluirla
este es el error:

Warning: include_once(elenco_base.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\EsteSoyYo\views\modules\elenco.php on line 2

Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'elenco_base.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\EsteSoyYo\views\modules\elenco.php on line 2

se que el problema tiene que estar en la ruta pero ya probé de todo y no logro que funcione

este es el código que conecta con la base:

```
<?php
$link = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=elenco';
$usuario = 'root';
$contraseña = 'root';


try {
    
    $pdo = new PDO($link, $usuario, $contraseña);

 } catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
?>
```

y este es el código donde intento incluirlo:

```
    <?php
include_once "elenco_base.php";

$elenco = 'SELECT * FROM elenco';
$gsent = $pdo->prepare($elenco);
$gsent->execute();

$resultado = $gsent->fetchAll();


?>

<div class="paginas">
    <h3>ELENCO</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">

            <?php foreach ($resultado as $dato): ?>

                <img class="galeria mx-auto d-block shadow" src="img/perfil1.jpg" alt="Ver bio de Gustavo Lauto" />

            <?php endforeach ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

espero puedan orientarme, gracias!
[image: captura de pantalla de directorios]

Comment: *`Failed to open stream: No such file or directory `* significa que no está encontrando el archivo. ¿En qué carpeta está `elenco_base.php` y en qué carpeta está el archivo donde haces el `include_once`?

Comment: están en la misma carpeta views/modules/

Comment: ¿Seguro que el archivo se llama **`elenco_base.php`**? ¿Podrías mostrar una captura de pantalla con tus directorios, donde se vean los archivos en cuestión?

Comment: Ahí subí una captura de pantalla

Comment: Las rutas están bien, esto `(include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')` hace pensar en un error con los symlinks. ¿Estás ejecutando xampp como administrador?

Comment: De todos modos, nunca es buena hacer include con rutas relativas, porque pueden fallar si el entorno apunta a otra parte o los symlinks funcionan mal o lo que sea es mejor definir tus rutas en constantes, en un archivo dedicado a ello, y luego incluir ese archivo y usar las constantes definidas. Así tienes todo mejor organizado y centralizado y si quieres cambiar algo lo cambias en ese archivo. Revisa el apartado **Otra posibilidad** en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).

Comment: si, estoy ejecutando como administrador. Voy a probar a definir las rutas en constantes. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Prueba usando `__DIR__` algo así como abajo, ahí modifica la ruta

```
include_once __DIR__ . '/elenco_base.php';
```

Comment: Hola, con __DIR__ tampoco me funciona

Comment: cambiaste la ruta?

Comment: Ya funciona! tenia un espacio entre el guion bajo y la b de base... Gracias!!