# ¿Cómo puedo pasar de una vista a otra en PHP?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap, aplicación-web

Lo que intento hacer es que cuando se de clic en mi NavBar te mande a esa pagina

```
<!-- NavBar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-primary" data-bs-theme="dark">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">FrissDent</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="index.php">Inicio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="informacion.php">Información</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="tratamiento.php">Tratamientos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="recursos.php">Recursos</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="mapa.php">Visitenos</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Estoy usando href y colocando el nombre de la vista con su extensión pero cuando clickeo en el navegador me dice la siguiente imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi carpeta desglosada con sus archivos almacenados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Hay una en específico que falla o son todas? ¿Verificaste que tienes un archivo con ese nombre y extensión? ¿Cuál es tu árbol de directorios? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Me pasa en todas las vistas. Las vistas están en una misma carpeta.

Comment: Estas usando algun framework? Revisa si tenes rutas definidas, el href="index.php", buscara un archivo llamado "index.php" en la ruta raiz del sitio, no lo buscara en "/views" por ejemplo

Comment: Uso bootstrap solamente, próximamente integrare más es un proyecto de una materia

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo donde está en navbar?

Comment: Se llama header.php,

Comment: Muy raro. ¿Podrías hacer clic derecho sobre alguno de los enlaces y luego darle a *copiar enlace* y comparar esa URL con la URL que hay en la barra del navegador?

Comment: Esa es la URL de de pagina predeterminada -> http://localhost/clinica/index.php cuando le doy clic al navbar para que me mande a otra pagina a través del hipervínculo ó referencia me sale la siguiente URL -> http://localhost/clinica/informacion.php

Comment: Pues eso, por lo que se ve, los archivos están dentro de la carpeta `admin/view`. Aunque el navbar esté en la carpeta `view`, sin embargo el mismo es incluido en `index.php`, y debes posicionarte desde `index.php`. Tienes que poner los `href` así: **`href="admin/view/informacion.php"`**, etc. Para evitar este tipo de situaciones lo mejor es definir las rutas en un solo archivo y luego usar las constantes en las que defines cada ruta.

Comment: Gracias, me funciono :)

Comment: Si te interesa el enfoque antes mencionado, revisa el apartado **Otra posibilidad** en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967). Y, cuando algo no funcione, considera depurar, en este caso, revisando las rutas de los enlaces y comparándolas con la ruta en la barra del navegador, habrías visto el problema inmediatamente.