# Problema al conectar php con BD con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, pdo, login

estoy tratando de hacer un sistema de registro y login, pero me esta siendo imposible conectar a la BD. Tengo 2 archivos, el de registro donde ponen los datos y el de database que es el que hace la conexión, y  en el registro llamo a éste con un require, pero me salta el siguiente error, como si no encontrara el archivo:

*Warning: require(database.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\finalphp\php\registro.php on line 2*

*Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'database.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\finalphp\php\registro.php:2 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\finalphp\php\registro.php on line 2*

Los dos están en la misma carpeta, he probado también poniendo la ruta absoluta, hasta con realpath, dirname... estoy estudiando empezando e igual se me pasa algo elemental pero no se ya que hacer. He probado a crear otros 2 archivos uno con un require y otro con un echo 'hola' y si que funciona el require de esa manera y se muestra el echo, así que no entiendo el fallo. Aquí el código:

```
<?php
    require 'database.php';
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registro</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/registro.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Regístrate</h1>

    <form action="registro.php" method="post"></form>
        <span id="erroruser"></span> <br>
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Usuario">
        <input type="password" name="contraseña" placeholder="Contraseña">
        <input type="password" name="confirmar_contraseña" placeholder="Confirma tu contraseña">
        <input type="text" name="email" value="" placeholder="Escribe tu e-mail">
        <input type="submit" value="send"> 
</body>
```

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';
    $database = 'users_web'; 

    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3307;dbname=users_web;charset=utf8','root','');
    } catch (PDOException $e)  {
        echo 'No se pudo conectar: '.$e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```

[image: Aquí está la ruta con los archivos]

Un saludo!!

Comment: ¿Seguro seguro que ambos archivos están en esta ruta: **`C:\xampp\htdocs\php\finalphp\php`**? Si nos muestras una captura de tu árbol de directorio, donde se vean los archivos implicados, podremos ayudarte mejor. Dicho eso, para evitar este tipo de problemas convendría definir tus rutas en un archivo, luego incluyes ese archivo y usas las constantes asignadas a cada ruta. Si te interesa este enfoque, revisa el apartado **Otra posibilidad** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967).

Comment: He puesto la imagen de la carpeta. Gracias por la alternativa, la probaré a ver si resuelve aunque me da rabia que en principio siendo algo tan sencillo como llamar a un archivo que esta en la misma carpeta tenga que complicarme tanto, me gustaría saber que falla porque no entiendo porque con un echo 'hola' funciona el require y con este código me dice que no lo encuentra, porque entonces no funcionaría tampoco el echo 'hola', y eso me tiene mosqueado

Comment: En la imagen veo que el archivo se llama `dabatase`, debería llamarse **`database`**

Comment: Madre mía que fallo más tonto... pero gracias por contestar, si no estaría aún dando vueltas al tema, un abrazo!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He recreado tu código y acá mis observaciones.

```
<?php
    $server = 'localhost';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;port=3307;dbname=users_web;charset=utf8", $username, $password);
        echo "Conectado !!!";
    } catch (PDOException $e)  {
        echo 'No se pudo conectar: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Ese código tiene la misma estructura del tuyo y funciona, te diré lo que vi:

1. Llamas **database** pero tu archivo tiene **dabatase**. En cuanto al error del require ese es.
2. Estas declarando variables que no usas, **$database** no sirve de nada pues va como parámetro en la línea de conexión => **dbname=users_web**.
3. Tienes **localhost** en variable y **127.0.0.1**, usa una sola cosa, mi script llama a la variable, la tuya jamás.

Yo creo que por lo demás todo esta bien, prueba mi código con el nombre del archivo bien escrito.

Comment: Si, antes si estaba usando las variables solo que como no sabía que estaba mal lo puse de otro modo y las dejé ahí. El fallo principal ha sido que el archivo estaba mal escrito -.-' pero muchas gracias! si no me lo hubieráis dicho estaría aún dándole vueltas