# PROBLEMAS CON EL DIRECCIONAMIENTO PHP EN REMOTO

Tags: php, html, mvc, rutas, host

Estoy en el proceso de publicación de un sitio web, el cual es **funcional en mi localhost** usando servidores Apache y MySQL con xampp. Esta contiene formularios html que direccionan a un archivo .php, es aquí donde esta el problema, el servidor remoto no busca bien la dirección que le propongo en el action del form.

Voy a entrar un poco mas en detalle. Estoy usando la estructura web de Model-Controller-View, suponiendo una estructura simplificada para este post:

1. Model

> 1. login.php

2. Controller

> 1. Conexion.php
> 2. admin.php
> 3. login.php

3. View

> 1. assets
> 2. login.php
> 3. index.php

Bien, en cada encabezado de cada pagina de view tengo su correspondiente:

```
include_once('../controller/Conexion.php');
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['email']) && isset($_SESSION['contrasena'])) {
    $login = $_SESSION['email'];
}
```

Donde me establece conexion sin problema con mi base de datos en el servidor remoto. Sino saldria un error HTTP 500.

Me dirijo a querer iniciar sesion, entro en mi login.php de view y me encuentro lo siguiente:

```
<form action="../model/login.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" autocomplete="on">
         <form action="../controller/admin.php" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post" autocomplete="on">

......

     </from>
</from>
```

Pulso el boton que ejecuta este formulario y ERROR 404 (no se ha enctrado el archivo). El servidor remoto(host) ha buscado dentro de view si existe *model/login.php* y *controller/admin.php*, ignorando completamente el ../
En cambio, en otras ocasiones como el *`include_once();`* o un *href de un `<a></a>`* no ignora el movimiento al directorio anterior. **Este es mi problema que quiero solucionar**

Ahora, también tengo otro problema, que es continuo a este.
Conseguí, de una manera no correcta para el funcionamiento de mi web que me lea el *login.php de model y controller*, y estableciese mi `$_SESSION`. Esto lo hice cambiando los nombres y introduciendo los *login.php de model y controller* en view, y después cambiando las rutas de los actions, y de lo demás necesario.

Observando el código de *login.php de model*:

```
<?php

session_start();

//var_dump($_POST);
//echo "<br>";

include("../controller/controlador.php");
include("../controller/login.php");

if ($_SESSION["carrito"]<>NULL) {
    $_POST['tempCarrito'] = $_SESSION["carrito"];
}

$correoElectronico = "";
$login = new Login();
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
$validado = $login->validar($_POST);


if ($validado == false) {
    $correoElectronico = $_POST['email'];
    echo ("<script>
        alert('No existe esta combinación de usuario y contraseña');      
        window.location='../view/login.php';
        </script>");

} else if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
    //var_dump($_SESSION);
    header("Location: ../view/index.php");
    die;
} else if ($_SESSION['admin'] == 0) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    unset($_SESSION['carrito']);
    //var_dump($_SESSION);
    header("Location: ../view/index.php");
    die;
} else {
    echo ("<script>
        alert('Ups! Algo ha ido mal, prueba de nuevo');      
        window.location='../view/login.php';
        </script>");
}

?>
```

Y cambiando las rutas de *los locations a index.php o login.php*(porque estamos en view): hago el intento de iniciar sesión con datos correctos, me entra en sesión pero no me redirige a index.php. Es decir, ignora completamente la funcion `header()`. **Este es mi segundo problema.** He visto por foros que este problema es muy comun, pero ne he visto la manera de solucionarlo para la estructura de web que yo tengo.

Mi host es IONOS, donde tienen servidores con sistemas Debian11, y claramente mi dominio redirige a la carpeta view donde se cuentra el index.php.

En resumen, quiero saber **como puedo volver a la ruta absoluta** y a partir de ahi poder indexar donde me apetezca, **haciéndolo funcionar en mi estructura MVC**.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Y porque pones `../` y también `../model` entiendo que siempre deberías apuntar al los controller

Comment: Tienes un formulario dentro de otro formulario??

Comment: Perdon, tienes razon, me he equivocado escribiendo le mensaje. El codigo que importo es del login de model no de controller.  Los form estan bien escritos. Y si, tengo un formulario dentro de otro, puede ocasionar problemas eso? Lo usamos porque admin.php tienen un comprobacionAdmin(), y asi conseguir sesiones diferentes desde la vista de un usuario y un adminiestrador

Comment: y el HTACCESS esta bien configurado??

Comment: Nota que entre una *ruta de URL* y una *ruta local* sus bases son diferentes.

Comment: No, el .htacces lo tenemos en blanco para las pruebas, despues diseñamos uno pero no tiene nada de efecto en el problema, simplemente son la redirecciones en el errores. Y si action de los form funciona con URL, como lo conseguio para mandar a mi carpeta model si estoy redireccionando el dominio a view

Comment: Realmente lo de las rutas es tu menor problema. Para solventarlo, puedes tenerlas definidas en un archivo en forma de cascada, incluir ese archivo y usar las constantes definidas. Así te evitas al problema actual y si hay que cambiar alguna ruta la cambias solamente en el archivo de definición. Revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/91541/29967) para más detalles. Peor que el problema de las rutas es que tengas un `form` dentro de otro `form`, o que mezcles código PHP con código Javascript. Son prácticas que deberías mejorar en lo adelante, según vayas adquiriendo conocimientos

Comment: En la explicacion de esa respuesta explica como hacerlo en codigo PHP, yo lo necesito para codigo HTML, y que el action del form lo sepa leer bien. He quitado el segundo form, pero era obsoleto, no tenia funcion ahi. Igualmente el error persiste. Y aunque mezcle codigo PHP y javascript, cuando los valores de inicio de sesion son correctos no tengo js, tengo la funcion header() que tambien sabe redireccionar bien

Comment: Creo que das demasiadas vueltas para explicar el problema concreto. Sabiendo que `../` sirve para **retroceder un directorio**, y si quieres poner una ruta en el `action` de un `form`, usa esa lógica adecuadamente para poner la ruta que sea, teniendo en cuenta el lugar en que se encuentra ese `form`. La cosa no tiene mayor misterio. Si no lo tienes claro, entonces, dinos **en qué archivo y carpeta está `form`** y dinos **a qué archivo de qué carpeta quieres ir desde el `action`**. Con esos dos datos bastará para responder a tu pregunta. El problema no aparece claro entre tantas explicaciones.

Comment: En el post digo donde esta cada cosa, aunque es un poco largo. El directorio root del remoto tiene las siguientes carpetas: **View, model y controller.** El `form ` se encuentra en un archivo **login.php de view** y lo quiero mandar a **login.php de model**. Lo lógico y lo que funciona en mi localhost seria: `../` *(retrocedo hacia atras)* `/model/login.php` *(indexo en mi archivo)* ¿no? Pues en el remoto no funciona.

Comment: Estas dispuesto a cambiar todo tu formato de rutas?? Porque si es así puedo responder a tu pregunta con un ejemplo de como lo hago yo, pero sino, sería desperdiciar tiempo en querer ayudarte para nada :-s

Comment: Es correcto. Si **`model`** y **`view`** están en el mismo directorio, y desde **`view`** quieres encontrar un archivo que está en **`model`**, tendrías que hacer `../model/elArchivoEnModel.php`. A no ser que tengas en el archivo `.htaccess` de **`model`** en este caso alguna regla que sobre-escriba las redirecciones. Convendría que nos muestres una captura de pantalla de tu árbol de directorios en remoto con los archivos desplegados, para comprobar que todo es como lo estás describiendo. Si es como dices, debería funcionar.

Comment: Ah, otra cosa que deberías verificar es si no hay código Javascript que está escuchando los envíos de formulario. Pues otra posibilidad es que sea ese código el que esté usando mal las rutas y causando el error 404. Y, convendría también que pongas el mensaje de error completo, para tener una idea de cuál es la ruta que está quedando mal.

Comment: No, ya se porque es. Tienes razón en lo que me dices. Pero ahora tengo un nuevo problema. El dominio estaba apuntando a la carpeta `view`, entonces cuando entras a la web no sabe leer para atrás por la toma como `root`. Lo he comprobado entrando desde el dominio de sistema de mi web y yendo a `/view`, a partir de ahí todo funciona como me funcionaba a mi en localhost :).  Mi problema ahora es, si en mi dominio (no el de sistema) apunto a `root`, ¿Cómo oculto view o el nombre que sea en la barra del navegador?