# Duda con el include php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Archivo nav.php , el que uso para incluirlo según sea el ticket_tipo del usuario luego de loguearse

```
<?php
  $active = array();

  for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){

    if($_GET['active']==$i){

      $active[$i] = 'active';
     }
    else{

      $active[$i] = "";
    }
  }

?>

<ul id="sesion" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro?');" href='scripts/scriptCierraSesion.php'><i class="fa fa-sign-out" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
</ul>
<ul id="tickets" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href='nuevoTicket-0'><i class="fa fa-plus-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Nueva Solicitud</a></li>
  <li><a href='tickets-sin-revisar-0'><i class="fa fa-pause" aria-hidden="true"></i> Solicitudes Pendientes <?php echo '<div class="notificacion">'.$resultado =$ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion).'</div>'; ?></a></li>
  <li><a href='tickets-revisados-0'><i class="fa fa-check-square" aria-hidden="true"></i> Solicitudes Cerradas</a></li>
</ul>

<nav style="margin-top:-10px">
  <div class="nav-wrapper blue darken-1">
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
<li class="<?=$active[8]?>"><a href="./index.php"><i class="fa fa-home" ></i> Inicio</a></li>    
<li class="<?=$active[5]?>"><a href="../../index.php"><i class="fa fa-desktop" ></i> Sistemas</a></li>

      <li class="<?=$active[0]?>" style="width:200px;text-align:center;"><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="tickets">Tickets <i class="fa fa-ticket" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
      <li class="<?=$active[3]?>"><a href='usuarios-3'><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mi perfil</a></li>
      <li class="<?=$active[6]?>"><a href='sugerencias-6'><i class="fa fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> Sugerencias</a></li>
      <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="sesion"><?=$_SESSION['ticket_usuario']?><i class="fa fa-chevron-down right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="#">Sistemas</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a href='nuevoTicket-0'>Nueva Solicitud</a></li>
      <li><a href='tickets-sin-revisar-1'>Solicitudes Pendientes</a></li>
      <li><a href='tickets-revisados-2'>Solicitudes Cerradas</a></li>
      <li><a href='usuarios-3'>Mi perfil</a></li>
      <li><a href='sugerencias-6'>Sugerencias</a></li>
      <li><a href='sugerencias-6'>Usuario: <?=$_SESSION['ticket_usuario']?></a></li>
      <li><a onclick="return confirm('Estas seguro?');" href='scripts/scriptCierraSesion.php'>Cerrar Sesion</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

El archivo ticket.class.php el que llamo con include en mi index para llamar las funciones necesarias

```
<?php

class Ticket{

    private $idUsuario;
    private $tipoSolicitud;
    private $prioridad;
    private $titulo;
    private $observacion;
    private $archivo;
    private $status;
    public  $fecha;
    private $respuesta;
    public  $hora;

    function setIdUsuario($idUsuario){
        $this->idUsuario = $idUsuario;
    }

    function setTipoSolicitud($TipoSolicitud){
        $this->tipoSolicitud = $TipoSolicitud;
    }

    function setPrioridad($Prioridad){
        $this->prioridad = $Prioridad;
    }

    function setTitulo($Titulo){
        $this->titulo = $Titulo;
    }

    function setObservacion($Observacion){
        $this->observacion = $Observacion;
    }

    function setArchivo($Archivo, $conexion){
        $this->archivo = $Archivo;
        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,"UPDATE ticket SET archivo='".$this->archivo."' WHERE id=".mysqli_insert_id($conexion)." ");
    }

    function setStatus($Status){
        $this->status = $Status;
    }

    function setFecha(){

        date_default_timezone_set('America/Manaus');
        $hora = new DateTime();
        $hora->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Manaus'));

        $this->fecha    = date("Y-m-d");
        $this->hora     = $hora->format("H:i:s");

    }

    function setRespuesta($respuesta){
        $this->respuesta = $respuesta;
    }

    function getId($conexion){
        return mysqli_insert_id($conexion);
    }

    function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){

        $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
        return $resultados[0];

    }

    function pendientesporrevisardos($conexion){

        $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 2 && status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
        return $resultados[0];

    }

}

?>
```

Y por ultimo el archivo que muestra los pendientes

```
<?php

require ("scripts/scriptValidaSession.php");
require ("clases/ticket.class.php");
require ("clases/baseDatos.class.php");
require ("clases/usuario.class.php");

?>

<style>
.notificacion {
  background: red;
   border-radius: 0.8em;
  -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  margin-right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.6em; 
}
</style>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>HelpDesk - Solicitudes pendientes</title>

        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
        <link href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="materialize/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><!-- ICONOS DE GOOGLE-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/autoRefresh.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/init.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            <?php

                if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 1){
                    echo "var myVar = setInterval(function(){autoRefresh()}, 3000);";
                }

            ?>

            window.addEventListener('focus', function() {
            document.title = 'HelpDesk - Solicitudes pendientes';
            $("#list").load(location.href+" #list>*","");

        });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/banner-top.png" alt="" width="100%" height="100px">
        <?php

//aqui se van a redireccionar los distintos menus del sistema 
//1 administrador ,2jefe de departamento, 3empleado, 4gerente ,5gerente general

if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] ==1 ) include_once("partes/nav.php"); //administrador
if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] ==2 ) include_once("partes/nav2.php"); //jefe de departamento
if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] ==3 ) include_once("partes/nav2.php");//empleado
if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] ==4 ) include_once("partes/nav2.php"); //gerente
if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] ==5 ) include_once("partes/nav2.php");//gerente general

        ?>
        <div class="card-panel grey lighten-4" style="padding: 0px 20px 20px 20px !important;">
            <table class="highlight responsive-table centered" id="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Ticket</th>
                        <th>Usuario</th>
                        <th>Departamento</th>
                        <th>Sede</th>
                        <th>Solicitud</th>
                        <th>Prioridad</th>
                        <th>Titulo</th>
                        <th>Adjunto</th>
                        <th>Estatus</th>
                        <th>Fecha</th>
                        <th>Hora</th>
                        <?php if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 1 || ($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] > 3 && $_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] < 6)): ?>
                        <td><a href="reporte.php" target="_blank"><i title="Descargar PDF" class=" glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></i></a></td>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        <?php

            $conexion = new baseDatos();

            if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
                echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
            }

            $ticket = new Ticket();

            if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 3){
                $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevisedEmpleado($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id']);
            }elseif($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 2){
                $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevisedSupervisor($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id_departamento']);
            }elseif($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 4){
                $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevisedGerente($conexion, $_SESSION['ticket_id_cede']);
            }elseif($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 1){
                $consulta = $ticket->listTicketUnrevised($conexion);
                $resultado = $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion);
                if($resultado > 0){ // validamos si es mayor a 0
                    ?>
                    <div align="" class="">TICKETS DE ANULACION PENDIENTES:<?php echo '<div class="notificacion">',$resultado,'</div>'; ?></div>
                    <?php 
                }

                $resultado = $ticket->pendientesporrevisardos($conexion);

                if($resultado > 0){ // validamos si es mayor a 0
                    ?>
                    <div align="" class="">TICKETS DE SOPORTE PENDIENTES:<?php echo '<div class="notificacion">',$resultado,'</div>'; ?></div>
                    <?php 
                }

            }
        ?>

        .....

        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

¿Por qué en mi archivo nav.php no carga lo mismo que carga en el archivo index? 
me dice que la variable ticket no esta definida , sin embargo la llamo en mi index y si aparece. ¿Qué debería agregar en el archivo nav para poder mostrar la información de `$resultado = $ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion);` en ese archivo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te recomiendo leer un poquito [Diferencias include, require, include_once y require_once](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66754/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-require-require-once-include-include-once-en-php). Por esa parte por lo que veo no hay problemas, pero es que no haz visto bien tu mensaje de error, tu mensaje de error no dice que no exista la clase dice que no existe la variable.

Por lo que estoy viendo en otra respuesta incluiste el error así:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: ticket in C:\xampp\...\nav2.php on line 63 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function pendientesporrevisar() on null in C:\xampp\...\nav2.php:63 Stack trace: #0
```

Este error te esta diciendo que la variable $ticket no existe por lo tanto tendrías que inicializarla, el error no es por que la clase no exista, si quieres llamar de forma estática la función dentro de la clase ticket primero tienes que declarar la función como estática y después llamar la función de forma estática:

```
class ticket{
    static public function pendientesporrevisar($conexion){
        $pendientes = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS conteo FROM ticket WHERE tipo_solicitud = 1 && status = 1 ")) or die("Error mostrando  tickets  pendientes: ".mysqli_error($conexion));
        $resultados = mysqli_fetch_row($pendientes);
        return $resultados[0];
    }
}
```

Y después llamar la función con:

```
ticket::pendientesporrevisar($conexion);
```

O como ya lo tienes definido pero primero crear el objeto de clase ticket para mandar mandar a llamar la función:

```
$lticketObject = new ticket();
$lticketObject->pendientesporrevisar($conexion);
```

---

Viendo la edición en la pregunta, las lineas de:

```
        $conexion = new baseDatos();

        if ($conexion->connect_errno) {

            echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
        }

        $ticket = new Ticket();
```

Las tienes después de cargar el archivo nav.php sería mejor que ese código estuviera después de que cargas los archivos class con el require y antes de la carga de los nav.php, te lo pegó a continuación también voy a bajar un poquito tus tags de  según la documentación de html el mejor lugar para poner esos tags sería en el head.

```
<?php

    require("scripts/scriptValidaSession.php");
    require("clases/ticket.class.php");
    require("clases/baseDatos.class.php");
    require("clases/usuario.class.php");

    $conexion = new baseDatos();

    if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
        echo "Fallo la conexion: ".$conexion->connect_error;
    }

    $ticket = new Ticket();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>HelpDesk - Solicitudes pendientes</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png" />
    <link href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="materialize/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet"><!-- ICONOS DE GOOGLE-->
    <style>

    .notificacion {
      background: red;
       border-radius: 0.8em;
      -moz-border-radius: 0.8em;
      -webkit-border-radius: 0.8em;
      color: #ffffff;
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: bold;
      line-height: 1.6em;
      margin-right: 15px;
      text-align: center;
      width: 1.6em; 
    }

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/autoRefresh.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="materialize/js/init.js"></script>

... El resto de tu código ...
```

Algo que veo en tu edición es que ya no se ve donde estas llamando en tu archivo nav.php la línea de:

```
$ticket->pendientesporrevisar($conexion);
```

Ya no la veo en tu código nav.

Comment: Gracias @Tabitha, leere esto mientras espero tu respuesta a la siguiente pregunta,¿ por qué en mi index si me toma el valor al llamarlo y no en el include? 

Que tendria que agregar en el include para poder ver la informacion que llamo de la funcion pendientesporrevisar en mi clase ticket como lo hago en mi index?

Comment: Tendría que ver el codigo del index, del nav y de ticket.class.pho, podria ser por que inicializas la variable $ticket despues de hacer el include

Comment: voy a corregir la pregunta para montar lo que necesitas para ayudarme

Comment: listo, ya corregi la pregunta añadiendo el codigo necesario

Comment: Perfecto! ya puse una opción extra en la respuesta

Comment: Quite esa linea porque me creaba el error.

Comment: Gracias , eso me da el chance de agregarlas al nav.php sin embargo me muestra errores en varias de mis ventanas

Comment: Pues podrías ir checando una por una de tus ventas seguro sólo tienes que mover la conexión y la variable hasta arriba en las otras ventanas también, tal vez podrías intentar eso de las llamadas estáticas o usar algo más sofisticado como el paradigma de diseño singleton para tus llamadas a base datos, el chiste sería buscar como crear los menos objetos posibles para no tener muchas conexiones en varias partes o perder el objeto que creaste en otra parte puedes leer esta documentación si te interesa https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton#PHP5

Comment: Mande a prueba una edición a la pregunta para que se vea más claro el código separado del texto de la pregunta, si vi que tu código tiene varios problemitas de abrir y no cerrar llaves de los if y de los while y de imprimir divs y otros tags dentro de un tag de tbody de la tabla etc, trata de identar bien tu código después va a ser mas fácil reelerlo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a validar si la clase existe, antes de llamarla en tu `nav.php`:

```
<?php
if (!class_exists("ticket"))
{
  require ("clases/ticket.class.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: hola @quinqui , pues , eso no hace nada . que me falta? 
que genere algun error? no veo la diferencia

Comment: ah , no habia ingresado el html en el archivo nav.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: ticket in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\sistemas\helpdesk\partes\nav2.php on line 63

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function pendientesporrevisar() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\sistemas\helpdesk\partes\nav2.php:63 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\sistemas\helpdesk\listTicketUnrevised.php(88): include_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\intranet\sistemas\helpdesk\partes\nav2.php on line 63

Comment: probe tu codigo con un alert en javascript asi 

`if (class_exists("ticket"))
{
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("hello!");</script>';
}` y si me muestra el alert :D

Comment: Entonces...? No me queda claro, te sirvió la respuesta? :o

Comment: No.  Tu codigo me dice que la clase esta . Cuando coloco el mismo codigo llamando a la funcion para reflejar el numero de pendientes   me dice que no esta definido. ¿Cómo puede no estarlo cuando la uso en el mismo documento html para mostrar los pendientes ?¿Es por el include? ¿sabes de eso ?

Comment: Uhm, supongo que me falta más información sobre tu código, me refiero, a que si puedes editar tu pregunta, colocando algo así como una maqueta o mapa de qué archivos hay y qué tienen cada uno dentro, ya que según lo había entendido, todo lo que mostraste en tu pregunta, estaba dentro del `index.php`... y si el problema lo tenías al intentar declarar la clase que ya había sido declarada, te servía mi respuesta. Ahora, si además tienes problema con una instancia de dicha clase, también le puedes aplicar un `if (isset($objeto))` o `is_object($objeto)` para saber si no existe, y así instanciarlo..