# Como hacer un llamado a una function php dentro de ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatables

me estoy aventurando a aprender DataTables y logicamente esto tiene mucho que ver con jquery, para implementarlo en mis proyectos y estoy aprendiendo de [Este Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RInf8KPptO0&t=0s&list=PLBZpL77Yun3rAHYeYH_NMUga3H8rarN3e&index=4) y me he encontrado con el siguiente codigo:

```
"ajax": {
            "method" : "POST",
            "url" : "listar.php"
```

Esta linea de codigo es con la finalidad de hacer un llamado a una web php que contiene un query, esa parte la voy entendiendo pero en mi proyecto los query los tengo concentrados en un archivo de functiones y me gustaria saber si es posible hacer un llamado a una function en particular.
**Mi archivo function.php**
Dentro de mi archivo poseo este query que es el que quiero implementar en la linea de codigo ajax.

```
function lista_usuarios2(){
    global $db,  $username, $usua, $mes, $accion, $res;
  /* variables */

   $query = "  SELECT * FROM users";

         $c = $db->query($query);
         while($data = $c->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
          {
    $arreglo ["data"][] = $data;
  }
  echo json_encode($arreglo);
}
```

Comment: Dado que `listar.php` es el archivo que se ejecutará cuando la petición Ajax sea lanzada, tienes que: 1. Poner al archivo que tiene a la función `lista_usuarios2()` en el contexto de `listar.php`, **si no está ya en el contexto**, sea mediante un `include` o un `require`. Si es una clase tendrás que crear una instancia de la misma. 2. Si hubiera que recuperar algún dato que se haya enviado vía Ajax (no parece ser el caso aquí) debes recuperar primero esa información. 3. Luego, finalmente llamas a la función: `lista_usuarios2()` y ésta te estará devolviendo los datos a Ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En este caso que expones, el funcionamiento sería así:

### `listar.php`

```
include('funciones.php');
lista_usuarios2();
```

Con esto estarías poniendo en el contexto de `listar.php` el archivo que contiene las funciones y en consecuencia haciéndolas disponibles para ser usadas en ese contexto.

Si el archivo ya está en el contexto, entonces no necesitas poner la línea del `include`. He de decir también que esto se puede hacer con `require`, con `require_once` o con `include_once`. Hay pequeñas diferencias entre ellos (existe aquí mismo una pregunta<sup>**1**</sup> con respuestas que explican tales diferencias).

#### Otros posibles casos

El código que muestras es de los más sencillos, porque tu función no necesita ningún parámetro. Pero puede haber funciones que necesiten datos venidos de la petición Ajax, que serían pasados a través de la opción `data` de Ajax.

En ese caso, **primero hay que recuperar esos datos y luego pasarlos a la función**. Veamos un ejemplo, suponiendo que haya una petición de listas por países en la que se envía el id del país que servirá para filtrar los datos:

#### Ajax:

```
"ajax": {
            method :  "POST",
            url :     "listar_pais.php",
            data :    {id_pais : 1},
            dataType: "json"
```

#### `listar_pais.php`

Aquí, dado que la variable del POST puede no ser incluida por el cliente, conviene hacer un control para emitir un mensaje erróneo en ese caso y no que el código falle sin que el usuario sepa por qué. Eso lo hacemos mediante un operador ternario.

```
$id_pais= ( empty($_POST["id_pais"]) ) ? NULL : $_POST["id_pais"];
if ( $id_pais ) {
    $mData=lista_pais($id_pais);
} else {
    $mData=array("error"=>"No se posteó el id del pais a buscar");
}
echo json_encode($mData);
```

El `echo` se hace desde aquí, no desde la función como en el primer caso, porque se espera un `return` de la función, además porque existe la posibilidad de fallo. Por eso, sea lo que sea se almacena en `$mData`, para luego devolverlo a Ajax.

#### `functions.php`

```
function lista_pais($id_pais) {
     /*
        * 1. Buscar por id_pais
        * 2. Guardarlo en un array
        * 3. Esta función debe terminar con algo como esto:
        *    return json_encode($arrResultante);
     */
}
```

> **Post-Data:** En la funciones de tu archivo debería existir un control más estricto. El código debe estar preparado para informar al
>   cliente de posibles errores. ¿Qué pasa si no hay conexión? ¿Qué pasa
>   si no encuentra datos? ¿Qué pasa si la consulta es errónea? En todos
>   esos fallos hipotéticos el código fallaría silenciosamente, ante la
>   incomprensión del cliente, que no recibirá para ninguno de esos casos
>   una respuesta o información adecuada.
>
> Cuando se trabaja con código de envío/recepción de datos hay que tener en cuenta que **el cliente
>   espera siempre una respuesta**: o bien los datos, o bien algún mensaje de error
>   que le indique lo que ha sucedido del lado del servidor. **Es deber del programador proveer esa respuesta**, sea cual sea.

---

#### Notas:

1. Ver la pregunta: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre require, require_once, include, include_once en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66754/29967)  y sus respuestas.