# PHP Recuperar datos de un archivo include para usar las variables en una consulta PDO MySQL (Falla)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Ya he consultado la lista de preguntas y, aunque algunas se parecen, ninguna llega a responder a mi problema. Después de tanto testear creo que no veo el problema y necesito opinión (y ayuda si es posible) de ojos nuevos en este código.

Tengo dos archivos configbdt.php y llamadabdatossli.php (los nombres no los puse yo). En llamadabdatossli.php he hecho un include de configbdy.php y pretendo usar sus variables para conectar a una base de datos con un PDO, ambos están en la misma carpeta, las rutas deberían estar bien. Muestro en contenido de ambos:

configdbt.php:

```
$usuario= 'jose';
$passw= '1234';
$databname = 'drupalfinal';
$table = 'imagenes';
```

llamadabdatossli.php:

```
require "configbdt.php";

function basedatosslider(){
$user = $usuario;
$pass = $passw;
$dbprefix = $databprefix;
$dbname = $databname;
$tabla = $table;

try { 
    $formod = '<details class="seven-details">
        <summary class="seven-details__summary insertarimgsli">
            <p>Insertar Slides</p>
        </summary>
        <div class="seven-details__wrapper details-wrapper">
            <div class="forminsertimgsli"></div>
        </div>
        </details>';

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY orden ASC");
    $sql->execute();
```

El problema viene una vez lanzo la consulta SQL y me encuentro con diversos errores:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database
>   selected in
>
> Error de conexión: PDOException: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied
>   for user 'jose'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Si pongo el usuario y contraseña me da el 1046 y si no pongo el usuario y contraseña y uso las variables me da el 1045.

Hice un echo de las variables y veo que, efectivamente, contienen el usuario, contraseña, base de datos y tabla. Podría haber usado los nombres tal cual estaban en configdbt, pero por abreviar un poco y hacer mas fácil la lectura hice lo de `$tabla = $table;` y demás.

Resumiendo: Las variables contienen texto, ese texto el PDO, por algún motivo, no lo recibe, no lo entiende como un string o algo, y no hay manera de que me haga la consulta porque dice que los campos donde están las variables están vacíos. Probé a poner 127.0.0.1 en lugar de localhost y no arregló nada, los mismo errores.

Toda ayuda es bienvenida. Si necesitais mas código decidlo y os lo pego por aquí, falta un catch y poco mas. Un saludo.

EDITO: Agrego otro error que ha lanzado, cambiando las variables. Este último sale al escribir el usuario pero dejar la variable que contiene la contraseña.

Comment: ¿Seguro que las credenciales son correctas? *`Access denied for user`*  hace pensar que ese usuario no tiene permiso para esa base de datos. ¿O, no será que tus variables están intercambiadas?  Prueba a poner los valores directamente, sin variables, a ver qué pasa. Si no te deja acceder revisa las credenciales.

Comment: Buenas tardes, gracias por tu interés. Si, si pongo las credenciales sin usar las variables, escritas tal cual, si me deja entrar y me muestra lo que debe mostrar. Pero si las pongo con las variables no hay manera. Es más, como vi que me daba un access denied, generé un usuario nuevo por esto mismo y me sucede lo mismo. Tienen ambos todos los permisos y, usando las variables no tira. Creo que las variables no las esta reconociendo el PDO, porque texto tienen y es correcto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acabo de ver el problema: estás haciendo el `require` fuera de la función, en ese caso las variables no son conocidas en el ámbito de la función.

Si lo haces así debería funcionar:

```
function basedatosslider(){
    require_once "configbdt.php";

    # ...

    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$databname", $usuario, $passw);

    # ...

}
```

He preferido poner `require_once`, por si la función es llamada varias veces<sup>1</sup>.

Además, no tienes por qué re-asignar las variables, puedes usarlas como se llaman en el otro archivo, porque las tienes tal cual en el contexto.

---

1. Ver las respuestas a: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre require, require_once, include, include_once en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66754/29967)

Comment: Te quiero tío. Efectivamente, no me había dado cuenta de que la estaba llamando fuera de la función. Estaba ya quemado con este código después de todo el día y no había visto la llamada fuera. Las variables las he dejado como estaban en el configdbt.php. Lo puse aquí así para facilitar la lectura, tanto mía como de quien pudiera verlo. Muchas gracias y un abrazo.

Comment: @Emerita me alegro de haberte ayudado a resolver este problema. Un abrazo.