# Como leer las variables de un archivo en una clase que esta en otro archivo

Tags: php, poo, funciones, pdo, variables

lo que quiero hacer es que la clase conexión lea las variables que tengo en otro archivo llamado vars.php que a su vez trae las variables desde una librería que se encarga de leer un archivo .env esto para que cuando pase el sistema a otras personas, estas solo tengan que configurar el archivo .env, lo que pasa es que al momento de tratar de leer la variable me sale que esta no esta definida pero solo cuando la intento llamar dentro de la clase, si la leo por fuera de la clase la toma perfectamente, no se como pasar la variable dentro de la clase.

Este es el código del .env

```
APP_NAME="Certificados"
MODE="dev"
#MODE="production"
APP_URL="http://localhost/proyecto-1/"
APP_URL2="https://****.com/"
ROL_ADMIN="1"

#Base de datos desarrollo
DB_CONNECTION="mysql"
DB_HOST="127.0.0.1"
#DB_PORT="3306"
DB_DATABASE="bd"
DB_USERNAME="root"
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

Este es el codigo del vars.php

```
<?php
require('../vendor/autoload.php');
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable('../');
$dotenv->load();
$mode = $_ENV['MODE'];
$appname = $_ENV['APP_NAME'];
$appurl = $_ENV['APP_URL'];
$appurl2 = $_ENV['APP_URL2'];
$menu = $appurl . 'view/menu.php';

//Variables de la base de datos
$DB_CONNECTION = $_ENV['DB_CONNECTION'];
$DB_HOST = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
$DB_PORT = $_ENV['DB_PORT'];
$DB_DATABASE = $_ENV['DB_DATABASE'];
$DB_USERNAME = $_ENV['DB_USERNAME'];
$DB_PASSWORD = $_ENV['DB_PASSWORD'];
```

Y este es el codigo que estoy intentando pero no lee las variables el del archivo conection.php

```
<?php
require('../view/vars.php');

$DB_CONNECTION;
$DB_HOST;
$DB_PORT;
$DB_DATABASE;
$DB_USERNAME;
$DB_PASSWORD;
//die($DB_CONNECTION);

class conection extends PDO
{

    private $dbConnection = $DB_CONNECTION;
    private $dbHost = $DB_HOST;
    private $dbPort =  $DB_PORT;
    private $db = $DB_DATABASE;
    private $dbUser = $DB_USERNAME;
    private $dbPass = $DB_PASSWORD;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $namex = '__construct';
        try {
            parent::__construct("{$this->dbConnection}:dbname={$this->db};host={$this->dbhost};charset=utf8",$this->dbUser,$this->dbPass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Ocurrio un error en: \"" . $namex . "\". Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    } 

    public function uploadDataRepart()
    {
        return $DB_CONNECTION;
    }

}
```

Intente también usar `$this->DB_CONNECTION` por si de pronto funcionaba pero no fue así

La funcion  que retorna el `DB_CONNECTION` es una prueba ya que pensé que estaba llamando mal el archivo y por eso también el `die()` comentado en la parte de arriba pero como digo no funciona ya que no detecta la variable dentro de la clase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

después de buscar un poco mas encontré este enlace con el que solucione el error

[Solución de lectura error de clase no lee las variables de otro archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/237618/php-recuperar-datos-de-un-archivo-include-para-usar-las-variables-en-una-consult?rq=1)

Resulta que para que los lea el require debe estar dentro de la función, dejo el código de como quedo mi archivo

conection.php

```
<?php

class conection extends PDO
{

    private $dbConnection;
    private $dbHost;
    private $dbPort;
    private $db;
    private $dbUser;
    private $dbPass;

    public function __construct()
    {
        require('../view/vars.php');

        $this->dbConnection = $DB_CONNECTION;
        $this->dbHost = $DB_HOST;
        $this->dbPort =  $DB_PORT;
        $this->db = $DB_DATABASE;
        $this->dbUser = $DB_USERNAME;
        $this->dbPass = $DB_PASSWORD;

        $namex = '__construct';
        try {
            parent::__construct("{$this->dbConnection}:dbname={$this->db};host={$this->dbhost};charset=utf8", $this->dbUser, $this->dbPass);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Ocurrio un error en: \"" . $namex . "\". Mensaje: " . $e->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }

    public function uploadDataRepart()
    {
        require('../view/vars.php');

        return $DB_CONNECTION;
    }
}
```

La función uploadDataRepart la voy a eliminar ya que esta va en otro archivo pero puse el require para ver si funcionaba y funciono correctamente