# Diferencias entre use y require , require_once , include , include_once

Tags: php, poo, php7, php5

La pregunta viene a ser eso, que diferencia existen entre principalmente `use` en php y los demás, pero tampoco tengo muy clara la diferencia. Hasta donde yo llego es a esto :

- `use`, por lo que entiendo es una forma de invocar **clases** en php desde otra clase , cuando se trabaja con `namespaces`.
- `require`, llamas a un **fichero** en concreto que invocas su contenido, si no lo encuentra da un `E_COMPILE_ERROR` y para la ejecución del programa.

> require is identical to include except upon failure it will also produce a fatal E_COMPILE_ERROR

[PHP : require](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)

- `require_once`, lo mismo de require, pero solo lo pide una vez.
- `include`es lo mismo que `require`.
- `include_once`es lo mismo que `require_once`.

Si me lo podéis explicar la diferencias entre `use` y los demás lo agradecería, por si se me escapa algo.

Comment: Te dejaré una respuesta para el caso de los `namespaces` por que para todo lo demás que mencionas ya existe una pregunta con respuesta aquí mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66754/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-require-require-once-include-include-once-en-php

Comment: si vas al manual de php podras ver lo que hace cada funcion https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.require.php

Answer (score 5):

Los espacios de nombre o `namespaces` en PHP son y cito de la documentación oficial

> Los espacios de nombres de PHP proporcionan una manera para agrupar clases, interfaces, funciones y constantes relacionadas. Un ejemplo de la sintaxis de los espacios de nombres de PHP:

Ejemplo: Declaramos una clase con un `namespace` llamado `App`, es decir la clase `Person` esta declarada y ahora solo existe bajo el contexto de esta declaración

archivo: Person.php

```
<?php 

namespace App;

class Person
{
    public function sayHi()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Ahora si queremos utilizarla dentro de otro archivo, por medio por ejemplo de la `instanciación` hacemos lo siguiente

archivo: People.php

```
<?php 

use App\Person as Usuario;

$nuevoUsuario = new Usuario();

echo $nuevoUsuario->sayHi();
```

Hacemos uso de `use` para invocar el nombre del `namespace` principal que engloba a `Person` que en este caso es `App` posterior con la contrabarra invocamos el nombre de la clase que deseamos obtener que es `Person`; opcionalmente podemos darle un alias a la invocación hecha por ejemplo `Usuario`.

Ya con lo anterior hecho podemos hacer el proceso de instanciación asignando al objeto `$nuevoUsuario` acceso a la clase `Person` con el alias `Usuario`

Ahora si ejecutamos este desde el navegador o la consola, obtendremos esto

> C:\Users\user>php People.php PHP Warning:  include(Persons.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\user\People.php on line 3

Lo anterior ocurre precisamente por que necesitamos *incluir* o *requerir* dicho archivo; entonces hacemos lo siguiente

```
<?php 

require_once 'Person.php';

use App\Person as Usuario;

$nuevoUsuario = new Usuario();

echo $nuevoUsuario->sayHi();
```

Y si ejecutamos desde consola o navegador veremos lo siguiente

> Hello World

Otro ejemplo

Mencioné mas arriba que `Person` solo existe dentro del contexto del namespace `App` por lo que si ahora creamos otro archivo mas llamado `Demo.php` y le agregamos lo siguiente

```
<?php 

require_once 'Person.php';

$nuevoObjeto = new Person();

echo $nuevoObjeto->sayHi();
```

¿Qué va a pasar si ejecutamos este código?

En teoría debería funcionar pues estamos creando una instancia de esa clase y aparte al inicio estamos requiriendo dicho archivo; sin embargo al ejecutar el resultado sería este:

> PHP Fatal Error: Uncaught Error: Class Person Not Found

Lo anterior se debe a que aunque estemos invocando al archivo, nos hace falta hacer uso `use` del namespace que la contiene o engloba dentro de si mismo; por lo que al no hacerlo no estamos accediendo a dicho contenido; caso contrario si hacemos lo siguiente justo después del `require_once` el problema queda resuelto

```
use App\Person;
```

Cabe destacar que desde PHP 7.0 y superior puedes importar múltiples nombres de clases de este modo

```
use App\Person\{ People1, People2, People3 };
```

Es decir dentro de la misma línea del `use` puedes mandar llamar entre *llaves* todos los nombres de clases que estan bajo el mismo `namespace` en este caso `Person`

Como punto final te comento que existe una práctica llamada la autocarga de clases a través de **PSR-4** te dejo un enlace para que consultes

Fuentes:

- [namespaces en PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.rationale.php)
- [psr-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)
- [namespaces agrupados](https://php.net/manual/es/language.namespaces.importing.php#language.namespaces.importing.group)