# Problema en el contenido de los correos electrónicos

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin

Estoy desarrollando un plugin para **WordPress** que se encarga de reportar pagos mediante un formulario al administrador, el administrador en su panel ve una tabla con los distintos reportes generados por el usuario, la acción es la siguiente: el administrador puede cambiar el estatus de los reportes masivamente o individual el resultado es notificarle a los clientes mediante correo electrónico si su pago fue rechazado o no. Yo cree una clase que me maneja los template de los correos electrónicos:

```
class HandlerTemplate{
    public $base_template = TEMPLATE_EMAIL;
    public $template;
    public function load_template(string $name_tamplate,array $data){
        ob_start();
        require_once $this->get_template($name_tamplate);
        $this->template = ob_get_contents();
        return $this->template;
    }
    private function get_template(string $name_template){
        $file = $this->base_template . $name_template . '.php';
        if(file_exists($file)){
            return $file;
        }else{
            wp_die('No se ha podido cargar el template del reporte, por favor verifique la ruta');
        }
    }
}
```

El problema es que cuando envío los correos a varios clientes osea cuando lo hago de forma masiva para notificar que su pago fue rechazado me llega el primer correo con el contenido de la plantilla pero los demás me llegan en blanco a los distintos clientes, pero si lo hago individual si lo hace bien, aquí el fragmento de código que recibe los datos:

```
if (!empty($data['cancelar'])) {
    $data_usuarios_correos_cancelado = $this->get_user_from_reports_payment($data['cancelar']);
    foreach ($data_usuarios_correos_cancelado as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key2 => $data) {
            $user_data  = get_userdata($data['usuario_id']);
            $user_name  = $user_data->display_name;
            $moneda     = $data['moneda'];
            $destino    = $data['banco_destino'];
            $referencia = $data['referencia_bancaria'];
            $monto      = $data['monto_reportado'];
            //Enviamos las notificaciones de los reportes y ordenes canceladas
            $this->notify_email_report_cancelled_user(new MailDT24, compact('user_name', 'moneda', 'destino', 'referencia', 'monto'));
            ob_end_clean();
        }
    }
}
```

Aquí el método que maneja el envio del correo:

```
public function notify_email_report_cancelled_user(MailerDT24 $mailerdt24, array $data_email)
{
    $template = $mailerdt24->load_template('report_payment_cancelled', $data_email);
    $mailerdt24->set_recipients_dt24('email@email.com');
    $mailerdt24->set_subject_dt24('¡Reporte de pago rechazado!');
    $mailerdt24->send_mail_dt24_with_format_woocommerce($template, 'Pago no encontrado');
}
```

De verdad no sé ya que hacer no se si el problema es en el buffer de salida ya he intentado con **ob_get_clean** y otras más.

Comment: Si cambias `ob_end_clean();` por `ob_get_clean()` podría funcionar con `include_once`. De todos modos no me parece una buena idea mandar mensajes dentro de un bucle si es el mismo contenido a distintas direcciones. Si la librería que usas permite enviar a varios destinatarios yo prepararía el contenido y una lista de destinatarios y enviaría un solo mensaje, así se hace una llamada al template.

Comment: No amigo la plantilla es dinámica en el contenido, varían valores como el banco el monto el nombre etc...

Comment: OK perfecto. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Listo ya solucioné el problema la diferencia estaba en el require_once lo cambien por un require la diferencia estre ambos esta en la documentación de PHP y en este enlace: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre require, require_once, include, include_once en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/66754/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-require-require-once-include-include-once-en-php)

Comment: Dicha diferencia la deberías agregar aquí, pues al momento es un tanto corta tu respuesta

Comment: Ya actualicé la respuesta. Saludos