# Como envió una variable que no sea por link

Tags: php

con el siguiente foreach se genera el menú de acuerdo a las materias que tiene un alumno en una base de datos, lo que se me complica es pasar esa variable de la materia al siguiente php para ocuparlo como una ruta en un gestor de archivos, en el código esta por link en el href y lo obtengo con un get, pero no me sirve de esa manera ya que conflictúa con mis funciones del otro php, alguna otra solución?..

```
<?php

session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > $_SESSION['setTiempoSession']) || !isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'])) {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    header('location: index.php');
} else {
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
}

include "sqlConexion.php";

$sql = "SELECT nombre FROM tabla_materias WHERE año = (SELECT grado FROM tabla_usuarios WHERE id=" . $_SESSION['id'] . ")";
$ejecucionSLQPDO = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$ejecucionSLQPDO->execute();

foreach ($ejecucionSLQPDO->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN) as $row) {

$root_dir = '';
$root_dir = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/archivos/' . $_SESSION['grado'] . '/' . $_SESSION['grupo'] . '/' . $row . '/' . $_SESSION['apellido_paterno'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['apellido_materno'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['nombre'];

if (!file_exists($root_dir)) {
    mkdir($root_dir, 0777, true);
}

echo
"<div class='contenedor' id='uno''>
        <a href='c.php?**materia=$row**'><img class='icon' src='materias.ico/$row.png'></a>
        <p class='texto'>$row</p>
        
        </div>";
}
?>
```

Comment: No entiendo del todo tu pregunta. Si estás en el entorno del servidor en ambos casos puedes usar `include`  para poner en contexto el contenido de un archivo PHP cualquiera. Si estás entre cliente y servidor entonces sí tendrías que pasar los datos *por link* como dices, o mejor aún usando Ajax.

Comment: @A.Cedano me podrías explicar como puedo usar el include para pasar la variable, cabe recalcar que necesito que la variable me almacene la materia en la cual estoy dando clic en el menú, en el href me funciona muy bien cuando doy clic en la materia que quiero pero no me sirve de esa manera ya que me malogra el siguiente php.

Comment: Simplemente pones `include('carpeta/archivo.php');`  y a partir de ahí podrás usar cualquier variable que haya en `archivo.php`. Lo que hace `include`  es poner en ese contexto el contenido de `archivo.php`  ... luego, hay varios tipos de inclusión y según el caso conviene usar uno u otro ([Revisa esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66754/29967)). Otra forma de poner datos en contexto es usando clases por ejemplo, todo depende de lo que quieres lograr finalmente y cómo quieres tener organizado tu código.

Comment: @A.Cedano es que con el href puedo pasar la materia a la cual le dan clic en el menú, con el include no lo creo, como esta dentro de un foreach, se ira reemplazando la materia hasta que la variable sea la ultima materia dentro de la generación del menú.

Comment: El hecho es que el problema no está explicado con claridad. Algo **muy importante** es que digas si estamos hablando de una **comunicación cliente/servidor**. O sea, una página cualquiera a la que se conecta cualquier usuario en la red (cliente)  la cual debe responder a acciones de ese usuario buscando/verficando cosas en el servidor. Si ese es el contexto, entonces lo que te convendría sería **usar Ajax** para pasar las acciones del cliente (usuario cualquiera de la web) al servidor, consultar lo que el cliente haya seleccionado y devolvérselo y/o actualizar su página.

Comment: Yo pasaría ID de materia en lugar del nombre, ese lo puedes obtener con una consulta que, además, te serviría para validar que el dato recibido es correcto (existe y la materia corresponde al usuario).

Comment: Puedes almacenar el dato mediante variables de sesión, un singleton (el considerado anti-patron por algunos) o por la url.
Una vez que te decidas por uno, podemos generar una respuesta.

Comment: @CésarAlejandroM como podría hacerlo tomando en cuenta que necesito que al momento de que le den click en el a href se almacene la variable a la cual le doy clic, cabe destacar que el menú se genera solo con el for each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay varias alternativas para solucionar tu propuesta, incluso se podría considerar que es una pregunta basada en opiniones, pero en este caso abordaré solo 2.

**Alternativa 1 - Local Storage**

**¿Qué es el local storage?**

En palabras muy simples es una API de almacenamiento web que permite almacenar datos en su par clave-valor sin necesidad de una base de datos, estos datos se almacenan en el navegador y tienen un limite de tamaño de 5MB (Para google chrome, otros navegadores soportan 10MB, pero por lógica y para que funcione en todos lados, no debes superar los 5MB).

**Ejemplo funcional del local storage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        li{
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 5px;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            width: auto;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: all .5s ease;
        }
        li:hover{
            background-color: black;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="id-menu-1">Texto menu 1</li>
        <li id="id-menu-2">Texto menu 2</li>
        <li id="id-menu-3">Texto menu 3</li>
        <li id="id-menu-4">Texto menu 4</li>
    <ul>
    <a href="#">go_to_utl</a>
    <button id="get_saved_option">Obtener opción almacenada</button>
    <button id="clear_saved_option">Limpiar opcion almacenada</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            let url = $(this).attr('href')
            let saved_option = localStorage.getItem("selected_option")
            url = `${url}?option_menu=${saved_option}`
            window.location.href = url
        })

        $('#menu li').click(function(e){
            if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
                // LocalStorage disponible
                let selected_option = $(this).attr('id')
                localStorage.setItem("selected_option", selected_option);
                console.log(`haz guardado el valor "${selected_option}" en el local storage`)
            } else {
                // LocalStorage no soportado en este navegador
                console.log("Este navegador no soporta local storage")
            }

        })

        $('#get_saved_option').click(function(e){
            let saved_option = localStorage.getItem("selected_option")
            alert(saved_option)
        })
        
        $('#clear_saved_option').click(function(e){
            let saved_option = localStorage.removeItem("selected_option")
            alert("La variable fue limpiada")
        })
    })
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Utilizar local storage te permitirá almacenar el valor y utilizarlo donde se te de la gana más tarde, aunque el la pagina se refresque.

Para enviar el valor a php puedes utilizar ajax o simplemente agregarlo a cualquier url que se le haga clic como en el ejemplo anterior.

**Alternativa 2 - pre-setear una variable en la url**

Con esta alternativa solo sabrás el valor en la pagina de destino, para implementarla solo debes definir una variable extra a la hora de renderizar la url y posteriormente rescatarla en la pagina php de destino.

```
href='destino.php?menu_option=hola'
```

Para recuperar el valor del menú, para ambas opciones, en tu fichero de destino debes tener algo como esto.

```
if(isset($_GET['menu_option']) && $_GET['menu_option'] == 'hola'){
    // Acá vienes de dicha opción del menú, haz algo
}
```

> En el titulo de la pregunta solicitas que no sea por "link", pero lamentablemente la selección del menú se realiza en el front-end y quieres recuperar el valor en el back-end, por lo cual, la comunicación debe realizarse mediante los verbos HTTP, por lo cual, no es posible lo que tu deseas, ya que más allá de que sea ajax, un acceso http/https regular, siempre estarás consumiendo un "link".
> La ultima opción serian websocket, pero, igual requerirás de un end point de conexión, así que en teoría está sujeta a un link.