# Imprimir un template con PHP

Tags: php, html

Tengo el siguiente código PHP:

```
<?php

$html               = $this->val("html");
$addIdModule        = $this->val("addIdModule");
$addClassModule     = $this->val("addClassModule");
$switchId = str_replace(".","-",microtime(true));




?>

<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template id="temp-card">
 
    <div class="templatecARD" data-group="0">

        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true' data-name="label_gruop">Tarifa</label>
        <input type="text" class="name_tarif" name="tarif"/>
        <button type="button" class="btn-event-disAble" title="Deshabilitar">X</button>
        
        <div>

            <div class="container-power"></div>
            <button class="btn-event-addPower" type="button" title="Añadir">+</button>

        </div>
        <div>

            <div class="container-energy" ></div>
            <button class="btn-event-addEnergy" type="button" title="Añadir">+</button>

        </div>

    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-power">
    <div class="box-power">
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true' data-name="labe_power">POWER</label>
        <div class="sortable_p" draggable="true">
                <input type="text" name="t_power"/>
                <input type="text" name="v_power"/>
                <button type="button" class="btn-event-disAble" title="Deshabilitar">X</button>
                <div class="draggl">
                    <div class="bar1"></div>
                    <div class="bar2"></div>
                    <div class="bar3"></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<template  id="temp-energy">
    <div class="box-energy" >
        <label class="lbl-tmp-crd" contenteditable='true' data-name="labe_energy">ENERGY</label>
        <div class="sortable_t" draggable="true">
            <input type="text" name="t_energy"/>
            <input type="text" name="v_energy"/>
            <button type="button" class="btn-event-disAble" title="Deshabilitar">X</button>
            <div class="draggl">
                <div class="bar1"></div>
                <div class="bar2"></div>
                <div class="bar3"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template> 
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->
<!-- TEMPLATES -->


    <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
<template id="temp-form">
    <form method="post">

        <div class="content-form"></div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn-event-sndFrm" type="button" title="Actualizar">UPDATE TEXTAREA</button>
            <button class="btn-event-addFrm" type="button" title="Añadir tarifa">+</button>
            <button class="btn-event-delFrm" type="button" title="Borrar tarifa">-</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</template>
            <!-- FORMULARIO -->
        <!-- FORMULARIO -->
    <!-- FORMULARIO -->

<div class="dv-content">
    <?=$this->getPublicNameModule() ?>

    ESTO SE TIENE QUE IMPRIMIR CADA VEZ QUE SE GENERE EL MODULO
    <div id="test-1"></div>
    <textarea id="test-atex-1" class="test-atex"> </textarea>
    <button class='btn-event-sndTo' type="button" title="Actualizar">UPDATE FORM</button>
</div>


<?php 

    $DOM = new DOMDocument();
    $DOM->loadHTMLFile( './formPage.php' );

    $p = $DOM->getElementsByTagName( 'template' );
    $p->length;
    // Recordad que en programación el primer número es cero.
    $p = $p->item(0);

    echo $DOM->saveHTML();
?>
```

En dicho código PHP hay varias template que NO se imprimen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede ver en la imagen, estoy trabajando con un módulo de `vertary`, en el cual, intento hacer que se imprima por pantalla los template.

Hasta ahora sólo se puede visualizar el `div.dv-content`, el cual contiene un textarea con un botón de "UPDATE FORM".

El caso, es que debería salir algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Un textarea y a su izquierda, un formulario dinámico. Eso es lo que contiene las `template`.

Hasta ahora he utilizado include, include_once, require y require_once, pero estos comandos solo sirven si están en OTRO archivo, por tanto, al estar las TEMPLATE en el mismo, no funciona.

Necesitaría pues, necesitaría poder imprimir por pantalla las `template` como en la segunda imagen (la cual, no tiene php, esto es cosa del `vertary` y su funcionamiento).

Comment: Podrías usar `include_once` o `require_once`. Revisa [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66754/29967) al respecto. De todos modos deberías organizar/optimizar para impedir que archivos se carguen o intenten cargarse sin necesidad.

Comment: Pero en este caso los `TEMPLATE` están en el mismo archivo donde los he de imprimir. No puedo usar require o include. Hasta ahora de lo que mi pobre cabeza piensa, debería obtener mediante un comando PHP el valor del template, y después imprimirlo, ¿pero cómo?

Comment: Entonces no entiendo tu pregunta ni por qué hablas de `require` y de `include`. Si están en el mismo archivo, ¿por qué se imprimen varias veces y dónde se imprimen?

Comment: No se imprimen, es el caso, lo que necesito es imprimirlas en DOM.

Comment: No entiendo. ¿Se imprimen o no se imprimen? Si tienes algún error pon en la pregunta el mensaje completo de error. El planteamiento es muy confuso.

Comment: Perdón, no se ni siquiera cómo plantearlo, estoy de prácticas y me han planteado este problema. He transcrito literalmente lo que me han pedido. No lo entiendo ni yo, esperaba que fuera solo cosa mia. Intentaré mejorarlo.

Comment: A veces el principal problema es no saber explicar el problema. Muchas veces explicándolo incluso encuentras la solución, te lo digo por experiencia propia. Haz un pequeño esfuerzo y trata de endenderlo/explicarlo de una forma simple. Entonces podremos ayudarte mejor. Cuando lo tengas pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: Hecho, lo edité de la mejor manera que he podido, con alguna imagen.