# Funcion redeclarada en php

Tags: php, sql, funciones, function, update

Tengo un archivo llamado `algoritmo.php` donde creo una funcion. Esa funcion la debo llamar en otro archivo diferente llamado `guardar_venta.php`. El problema es que estoy redeclarando esa funcion en el archivo `guardar_venta.php`. Lo que causa este error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare descuentaCantidad() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\modulo_venta\algoritmo.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\modulo_venta\algoritmo.php on line 25
```

Este es el archivo `algoritmo.php` :

```
  <?php

function descuentaCantidad($prod,  $c)
{


    include("../includes/conexion.php");


    $sql = "SELECT unidades_disponibles  From tblproductoterminado where codigo='$prod'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);


    $cantidad1 = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];

    $cantidadNueva = abs($c - $cantidad1);

    $sql = "UPDATE tblproductoterminado set unidades_disponibles = '$cantidadNueva' where codigo = '$prod'";


    mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);

    return $sql;
}



?>
```

Y este es el archivo `guardar_venta.php` :

```
    <?php
include "../includes/conexion.php";

$numero = $_POST["numero"];
$cliente = $_POST["cliente"];
$fecha = $_POST["fecha"];
$forma_pago = $_POST["forma_pago"];

// Los siguientes son arreglos, todos con la misma cantidad de elementos
$producto = $_POST["codigo"]; 
$cantidad = $_POST["cantidad"];
$precio_unitario = $_POST["precio_unitario"];


//llamar procedimiento 
$proc = $conexion->prepare(" CALL sp_InsertarFacturaventa('$numero','$cliente','$fecha','$forma_pago')");

//ejecutar procedimiento
$resultado_venta = $proc->execute();


// Haces un ciclo para recorrer uno de los campos y usar el mismo índice para los otros:
foreach($producto as $index => $prod) {
    // Los elementos de arreglo deben encerrarse entre llaves
    $guardar_venta_producto = "INSERT INTO tblfacturventaproducto (factura_venta, producto, cantidad, precio_unitario)
        VALUES ('$numero', '$prod', '{$cantidad[$index]}', '{$precio_unitario[$index]}')";
    // Aquí ejecutas la consulta para insertar este producto
    $resultado_productos = $conexion->query($guardar_venta_producto);

   //------------------VARIABLE QUE SE UTILIZA EN LA FUNCION---------------------------------
    $c = $cantidad[$index];
    //---------------ARCHIVO DONDE ESTA LA FUNCION----------------------------------------------
    include "algoritmo.php";
    
}
 
//----------------------------------AQUI LLAMO LA FUNCION-----------------------
 
descuentaCantidad($prod ,  $c);




if ($resultado_venta && $resultado_productos) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Factura Creada!");
    window.location.href="registrar_venta.php";
    </script>';

} else {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Algo falló! Volver a intentar. Revisar que el número de factura no este repetido");
    window.location.href="registrar_venta.php";
    </script>';  
    
    // echo "Error: {$conexion->error}";
} 
include "../includes/desconexion.php";
```

En el lugar donde esta  `include "algoritmo.php";`  es dentro de el `foreach` ya que arriba esta la variable `$c` que guarda  un valor que es creado directamente dentro del `foreach`.
Llamo la funcion afuera del `foreach` asi: `descuentaCantidad($prod ,  $c);`.

Comment: Si es la misma función, ¿por qué tienes que tenerla dos veces en el mismo contexto? Si no es la misma función, ¿por qué se llaman igual?

Comment: @A.Cedano es la misma funcion. la tengo dos veces en el mismo contexto porque en una parte la estoy creando y la otra parte intento llamarla. Sin embargo parace que lo estoy haciendo mal

Comment: No. La llamada a la función es correcta. El mensaje de error es claro: *`Fatal error: Cannot redeclare descuentaCantidad() (previously declared in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\modulo_venta\algoritmo.php:3) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sistema\modulo_venta\algoritmo.php on line 25`* Te dice que estás declarando la función dos veces, **en el archivo `algoritmo.php`** una vez en la **línea 3** y otra vez en la **línea 25**. Se entiende muy fácil, sepas o no inglés.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya veo.. en la linea 3 esta ´ function MateriaVencida($codigo , $unidades_disponibles){´ y en la linea 25 se cierra a funcion ´}´ . Entonces no entiendo donde la estoy redeclarando

Comment: Pulsa en [edit]  y pon todo el contenido de `algoritmo.php` para revisarlo.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya. hay una parte en la pregunta que dice "Este es el archivo algoritmo.php :" Hay esta todo lo que esta en el archivo.

Comment: ¿No dices que en la línea 3 hay una función llamada `MateriaVencida`? Yo esa función no la veo. Otra cosa muy extraña es que haces include de `algoritmo.php` dentro de un bucle, ¿por qué haces ese include ahí. Y, si el contenido de `algoritmo.php` es todo lo que pones en la pregunta, entonces revisa el archivo `conexion.php`, porque entonces será allí donde defines de nuevo la función `descuentaCantidad()` . Para este tipo de casos necesitamos ver el contexto completo para detectar el error.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120588/discussion-between-karol-and-a-cedano).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás haciendo un `include` dentro de un bucle:

```
foreach($producto as $index => $prod) {
    // ...

    include "algoritmo.php";

    // ...
}
```

Significa que ese archivo se incluirá `N` veces, siendo `N` el número de iteracciones que ocurran en el bucle. Si son 100 iteracciones, estarían incluyendo el archivo 100 veces, si son 1000 iteracciones, 1000 inclusiones. Eso mismo estaría causando `N` intentos de definición de la función que hay en ese archivo.

Si necesitas algún elemento que está en `algoritmo.php`  basta con incluirlo una sola vez, y ya tendrás a mano todo lo que haya en el archivo.

Por ejemplo:

```
#Incluyes el archivo UNA SOLA VEZ no N veces
include "algoritmo.php";

foreach($producto as $index => $prod) {
    // ...

    #Aquí puedes usar cualquier elemento que esté en algoritmo.php

    // ...
}
```

Cuando tengas que incluir archivos que pudieran ser incluidos varias veces (aunque lo mejor es tener un control claro de tu contexto y una organización del código que impida que esto ocurra), es recomendable usar `include_once` o `require_once`, los cuales incluirían el archivo una sola vez, evitando duplicados. Para más detalles puedes consultar la pregunta: [¿Cuál es la diferencia entre require, require_once, include, include_once en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/66754/29967)